# Why does string to number comparison work in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare a value coming from a HTML text field with integers. And it works as expected.
Condition is -

```
x >= 1 && x <= 999;
```

Where `x` is the value of text field. Condition returns `true` whenever value is between 1-999 (inclusive), else `false`.
Problem is, that the value coming from the text field is of string type and I'm comparing it with integer types. Is it okay to have this comparison like this or should I use parseInt() to convert `x` to integer ?

Comment: You don't need parseInt().  When comparing numbers with strings, JavaScript casts the strings to numbers if possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because JavaScript defines `>=` and `<=` (and several other operators) in a way that allows them to coerce their operands to different types. It's just part of the definition of the operator.

In the case of `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`, the gory details are laid out in [§11.8.5 of the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5). The short version is: If both operands are strings (after having been coerced from objects, if necessary), it does a string comparison. Otherwise, it coerces the operands to numbers and does a numeric comparison.

Consequently, you get fun results, like that `"90" > "100"` (both are strings, it's a string comparison) but `"90" < 100` (one of them is a number, it's a numeric comparison). :-)

> Is it okay to have this comparison like this or should I use parseInt() to convert x to integer ?

That's a matter of opinion. Some people think it's totally fine to rely on the implicit coercion; others think it isn't. There are some objective arguments. For instance, suppose you relied on implicit conversion and it was fine because you had those numeric constants, but later you were comparing `x` to another value you got from an input field. Now you're comparing strings, but the code *looks* the same. But again, it's a matter of opinion and you should make your own choice.

If you do decide to explicitly convert to numbers first, `parseInt` may or may not be what you want, and it **doesn't** do the same thing as the implicit conversion. Here's a rundown of options:

- `parseInt(str[, radix])` - Converts as much of the beginning of the string as it can into a whole (integer) number, **ignoring extra characters at the end**. So `parseInt("10x")` is `10`; the `x` is ignored. Supports an optional radix (number base) argument, so `parseInt("15", 16)` is `21` (`15` in hex). If there's no radix, assumes decimal unless the string starts with `0x` (or `0X`), in which case it skips those and assumes hex. Does **not** look for the new `0b` (binary) or `0o` (new style octal) prefixes; both of those parse as `0`. *(Some browsers used to treat strings starting with `0` as octal; that behavior was never specified, and was [specifically disallowed][2] in the ES5 specification.)* Returns `NaN` if no parseable digits are found.
- `Number.parseInt(str[, radix])` - Exactly the same function as `parseInt` above. (Literally, `Number.parseInt === parseInt` is `true`.)
- `parseFloat(str)` - Like `parseInt`, but does floating-point numbers and only supports decimal. Again extra characters on the string are ignored, so `parseFloat("10.5x")` is `10.5` (the `x` is ignored). As only decimal is supported, `parseFloat("0x15")` is `0` (because parsing ends at the `x`). Returns `NaN` if no parseable digits are found.
- `Number.parseFloat(str)` - Exactly the same function as `parseFloat` above.
- Unary `+`, e.g. `+str` - *(E.g., implicit conversion)* Converts the *entire* string to a number using floating point and JavaScript's standard number notation (just digits and a decimal point = decimal; `0x` prefix = hex; `0b` = binary [ES2015+]; `0o` prefix = octal [ES2015+]; **some** implementations extend it to treat a leading `0` as octal, but not in strict mode). `+"10x"` is `NaN` because the `x` is **not** ignored. `+"10"` is `10`, `+"10.5"` is `10.5`, `+"0x15"` is `21`, `+"0o10"` is `8` [ES2015+], `+"0b101"` is `5` [ES2015+]. Has a gotcha: `+""` is `0`, not `NaN` as you might expect.
- `Number(str)` - Exactly like implicit conversion (e.g., like the unary `+` above), but slower on some implementations. *(Not that it's likely to matter.)*
- Bitwise OR with zero, e.g. `str|0` - Implicit conversion, like `+str`, but then it also converts the number to a 32-bit integer (and converts `NaN` to `0` if the string cannot be converted to a valid number).

So if it's okay that extra bits on the string are ignored, `parseInt` or `parseFloat` are fine. `parseInt` is quite handy for specifying radix. Unary `+` is useful for ensuring the *entire* string is considered. Takes your choice. :-)

For what it's worth, I tend to use this function:

```
const parseNumber = (str) => str ? +str : NaN;
```

*(Or a variant that trims whitespace.)* Note how it handles the issue with `+""` being `0`.

And finally: If you're converting to number and want to know whether the result is `NaN`, you might be tempted to do `if (convertedValue === NaN)`. But **that won't work**, because as Rick [points out below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#comment46238568_28994875), comparisons involving `NaN` are always false. Instead, it's `if (isNaN(convertedValue))`.

Comment: Another fun fact:  If the string cannot be cast to number, it's treated as `NaN`.  `NaN` compared to anything (including itself) is false. Therefore,all of these expressions are false:  `'a' == 5`, `'a' < 5`, `'a' > 5`

Comment: @Bergi - **AND** converts `NaN` to `0`. Just added that today and clearly wasn't completely awake. Thanks for flagging it up! Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The [**MDN's docs on Comparision**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) states that the operands are converted to a common type before comparing (with the operator you're using):

> The more commonly used abstract comparison (e.g. ==) converts the operands to the same Type before making the comparison. For relational abstract comparisons (e.g., <=), the operands are first converted to primitives, then to the same type, before comparison.

You'd only need to apply `parseInt()` if you were using a strict comparision, that does not perform the auto casting before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `parseInt` if the var is a string. Add = to compare `datatype` value:

```
parseInt(x) >== 1 && parseInt(x) <== 999;
```