# Wrong variable data

Tags: javascript, html, formatting

happy new year!

Here is my code:

```
var totalwin,pradinisStatymas

function Increase()
{
    ....
    ....
    totalwin += pradinisStatymas; //I'm adding increasing totalwin by pradinisStatymas
    return print();
}


function print()
{
    locale[lang][7] = "Total win: ";
    var a="<br>"+locale[lang][7]+totalwin+"<br>";
    bot_debug(a,0);
}

$bCons = $("#botConsole");
function bot_debug(text,type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case 0:{$bCons.css("color","#353535"); $bCons.html(text); break;}
        case 1:{$bCons.css("color","#C12E2A"); $bCons.html(text); break;}
        case 2:{$bCons.css("color","#419641"); $bCons.html(text); break;}
    }
}
```

The problem is, if I set "pradinisStatymas" to 5, it should change $bCons's text to "*Total win: 5*", but instead it changes text to "*Total win: 05*".

If I increase it even further, it will keep adding the pradinisStatymas value at the end "*Total win: 055*".

It was working fine when I was using javascript console instead of html text.
I think I need to do some formatting, but I'm not sure how.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing _String_ and _Number_, causing the `+` operator to do _string concatenation_ instead of _addition_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've left out the important bit, which is how/where you're getting `pradinisStatymas`, but the symptom makes the problem fairly clear: The value in `pradinisStatymas` is a *string*. (Perhaps you're getting it from an `input` element's `value`.) So `+=` is string concatenation, not addition.

If we assume that `totalwin` is set to `0` initially (and thus is a number to start with), convert `pradinisStatymas` to a number before the `+=`, e.g.:

```
totalwin += +pradinisStatymas;
// or
totalwin += Number(pradinisStatymas);
// or (if it's meant to be an integer)
totalwin += parseInt(pradinisStatymas, 10);
// or
totalwin += parseFloat(pradinisStatymas);
```

Those are some of your options, the third one one assumes that is meant to be an integer (whole number). My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28994875/157247) goes into detail of the various options.

Comment: As we don't know how `totalwin` is set either, it may be wise to do `foo = +foo + +bar` instead of `foo += +bar`

Comment: In your first case, `+pradinisStatymas`, does the `+` convert a string to a number? I'd like to read up more on that.

Comment: @christofr: Yes, `+n` does exactly what `Number(n)` does, but without the function call and the possibility of someone shadowing the `Number` symbol (unlikely, but...).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @T.J.Crowder!