# Looping through an input with the type of number

Tags: javascript

I'm obviously very very new to javascript.
What I have is an input with the type number with an minimum of 1 and a maximum of 31.  I'm asking the user to select the date they were born.
However, I am unsure on how to retrieve the users value.  If it was a select box with options I could get it but the requirements for the assignment are to use an input box  with the type number.
I would appreciate any guidance on how to do this, I've been looking up different sources for 3 hours and i'm sure it's very simple, I'm just not seeing it

this is my html:

```
   <label for="birth_day">Please select your birthday:</label>
         <input type="number" name="birthday" id="birthday"
         min="1" max="31">
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

The value of an [`input` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#htmlinputelement) is available from its [`value` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-value):

```
var v = document.getElementById("birthday").value;
```

It will be a string, even with the `input type="number"`, so you'll want to parse it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28994875/157247) goes into several ways you can do that, depending on what behavior you want, although with an `input type="number"` simply doing `var n = +v;` is probably sufficient.

Comment: Thanks guys,  I was thinking it needed to be in an array or to use a for loop.   Very simple

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other input value, see this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nccy0nLj/)

```
<input type="number" name="birthday" id="birthday"
         min="1" max="31" onblur="alertValue(this)">

function alertValue(thisObj)
{
   alert( thisObj.value ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said it IS simple. You can use pure javascript for it or you can use jQuery library.

With JavaScript:

```
//you get the value by id
var value = document.getElementById("birthday").value;

//or you can get by tag name; element type;
var value = document.getElementsByTagName("input").value;
```

The first one is more specific, since you can have several input elements on the page.

With jQuery:

```
 //
 $( "input[name='birthday']" ).val();
```

Check jQuery doc. it is very informative with examples. [Selecting Elements with jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)

Best regards,