# if/else operators not changing

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, operators

I'm coding a game with different GameOver Text according to the score

Here's the code :

```
<div id="game-over">
      <h3><font color="orange">Tu as courus <span id="score"></span> mètres.</font></h3>
      <font color="orange"><h1 id="customegotext">oldHeader</h1></font>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button restart">Ressayer ?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<script>
    var scoretext;
    if (score < 45) {
        scoretext = "Text1";
    } else if (score > 100 ) {
        scoretext = "Text2";
    } else if (score > 500 ) {
        scoretext = "Text3";
    } else if (score > 750 ) {
        scoretext = "Text4";
    } else {
        scoretext = "Text5";
    }
    document.getElementById("customegotext").innerHTML = scoretext;
</script>
```

The problem is that it always show "text5" whatever the score is.

Thank you for helping

Precision :

- All of the code is in the index.HTML file
- The value "score" is defined in a .JS file by this code

  // define variables
  var player, score, stop, ticker;
- I'm a beginner in coding

Comment: Where did you define the `score` variable?

Comment: Are you loading your JS file before or after the code you have shown? How does the `score` variable get updated?

Comment: Post your complete index.html and js please.

Comment: The complete code is WAY to long but here's a pastebin : http://pastebin.com/Xd6UFQqR

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that it always show "text5" whatever the score is.

There are two reasons for that:

1. `score` is an HTMLElement, not a number. It's an automatic global variable created by the browser because you've given the element `id="score"`. To access its value, you'd use `score.value`, which is a *string*. You can convert that string to a number in various ways; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28994875/157247) describes them.
2. You're running your script, just once, at the outset. Nothing will make it run automatically later when the value of the `score` element changes. You need to do that on purpose. Search for "JavaScript event handling," "DOM event handling," or similar to see how to set up DOM event handlers.

---

Side note: I don't like to rely on automatic globals, not least because the global namespace in browsers is **incredibly** crowded and some `id` values don't get an automatic global because they would conflict with an existing global. Instead, I suggest using `document.getElementById("score")` to get the HTMLElement instance.

Answer (score 1):

Js is not aware of the html content which change, so you have to check out what is the value inside the span like this :

```
var score = document.getElementById("score").value;
```

You have to define score each time you want to reset the text.

Furthermore, your script is executed only one time when you open the page, so it will get the value of the default html which is `undefined` because your span is empty. This is why you get `"Text5"`.

If you want to do this dynamically, you have to create an event, for example when the user click on a button.

Comment: Excuse me but this code should go to the html file or javascript

Comment: This is javascript language so you can add it in the script balise or in an external file