# Make sum of object properties from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have to get the sum of unit_price numbers. How can I do that?

The array looks like this:

```
 $scope.items = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Phone',
        quantity: '1',
        unit_price: '200'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'IPhone',
        quantity: '1',
        unit_price: '240'
    }
];
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and some effort

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You `reduce` the array:

```
var total = $scope.items.reduce(function(x,y) { return x + parseInt(y.unit_price) }, 0);
```

Comment: This is the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var sum = 0;
angular.forEach($scope.items, function(value, key){
    sum = sum + value.unit_price;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you *can* use `reduce` for this, there's no reason to and it's easy to get wrong. (`reduce` is useful if you're doing functional programming with predefined, reusable reducers; otherwise, it's just overcomplicated.)

A simple loop is all you need, perhaps with some destructuring:

```
let sum = 0;
for (const {unit_price} of $scope.items) {
    sum += +unit_price;
//         ^−−−−−−−−−−− converts your strings to numbers
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const $scope = {};
$scope.items = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Phone',
        quantity: '1',
        unit_price: '200'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'IPhone',
        quantity: '1',
        unit_price: '240'
    }
];

let sum = 0;
for (const {unit_price} of $scope.items) {
    sum += +unit_price;
}

console.log(sum);
```

Re converting your `unit_price` strings to numbers: My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) lists your various options for doing that, with some pros and cons for each. I've used the unary `+` above, but there are other options.