# Inconsistent behaviour when using process.argv in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my first day learning Node and I'm trying to implement a program that returns the sum to N numbers where N is the input. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Node installed using the package manager (v0.10.25). Here is my code

```
var myNumber = process.argv[2]
var sumToMyNumber =  myNumber*(myNumber+1)*0.5
console.log(sumToMyNumber)
```

The program file is `SumToN.js`, and the output is

```
nodejs SumToN.js 5 // 127.5
```

However, executing the code with `var myNumber = 5` returns the right answer. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`process.argv[2]` will be a **string**. When you use `*` with a string, it's implicitly converted to a number, but when you use `+` when one of the operands is a string, it's string concatenation.

So for instance, if you gave 20 on the command line, that calculation becomes

```
var sumToMyNumber =  "20"*("20"+1)*0.5
```

which is

```
var sumToMyNumber =  "20"*("201")*0.5
```

which is

```
var sumToMyNumber =  20*(201)*0.5
```

which is 2010, where you probably wanted 210.

Convert `myNumber` to a number before doing the calculation:

```
var myNumber = +process.argv[2];
// ------------^
```

or

```
var myNumber = Number(process.argv[2]);
// ------------^^^^^^^---------------^
```

or

```
var myNumber = parseFloat(process.argv[2]);
// ------------^^^^^^^^^^----------------^
```

or

```
var myNumber = parseInt(process.argv[2]);
// ------------^^^^^^^^----------------^
```

depending on your needs. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28994875/157247) has a rundown of how those differ.

Answer (score 1):

`process.argv` arguments come in as strings.

So you will get the same result inside the program by setting `myNumber` like this:

```
var myNumber = "5";
```

Instead you need to use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to parse the string into an integer. Or other `parse*` functions if you want to support floats etc.

Answer (score 0):

`process.argv[2]` is being interpreted as a string.

So, `'5' * ('5'+1) * 0.5` becomes `'5' * '51' * 0.5` becomes `5 * 51 * 0.5` (which is 127.5).

Make sure you convert it to a Number!

`var myNumber = Number(process.argv[2])`