# How do I get a number recognized by Javascript's "document.getElementById" script operators?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a number from a *document.getElementById* to be read as a real number in a *if/else* statement using a comparison operator (e.g.: points < 40). Below is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish using w3school's tool to assist.

I understand Javascript does certain things depending on the *DataTypes*, *Operators*, and *Numbers*. Below is the original code I started with, but I have tried different variations, see below with the datatype outcome commented to the right. I used arithmetic to find out what's going on with my element's id number when pulled into the variable and the best outcome is *NaN*.

**How do I get a number within an HTML tag to be recognized by Javascript's *document.getElementById* script operators?**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<span id="points">39</span> is <span id="outcome"></span>

<script>

    var points = document.getElementById("points"); // [object HTMLSpanElement]
    //var points = +document.getElementById("points"); // NaN
    //var points = parseInt(document.getElementById("points")); // NaN 
    //var points = Number(document.getElementById("points")); // NaN
    if (points < 40) {document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML = "LESS THAN 40";}
    else {document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML = "40 or GREATER";}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** All that was needed was a ".innerHTML" addition to my var (added before the semicolon).

**FIXED CODE BELOW:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<span id="points">39</span> is <span id="outcome"></span>

<script>

    var points = document.getElementById("points").innerHTML; // [object HTMLSpanElement]
    //var points = +document.getElementById("points"); // NaN
    //var points = parseInt(document.getElementById("points")); // NaN 
    //var points = Number(document.getElementById("points")); // NaN
    if (points < 40) {document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML = "LESS THAN 40";}
    else {document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML = "40 or GREATER";}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An HTML element will never be a number. As you already showed, `document.getElementById("points"); // [object HTMLSpanElement]` you have a span, not a number. What you want is the `.value` or the `innerHTML` or the `innerText` of the span.

Comment: And then you should ideally `parseInt` what you get from `.value`

Comment: Just use single quotes or escape them.

Comment: @csmckelvey - Adding .innerHTML to the end of my var points worked. Thank you. - If your reply was an answer I would up vote it... Btw, I asked in a comment I previously deleted how I can make the innerHTML of my else statement contain an HTML tag with quotes, hints csmckelvey's follow up comment, which worked: _.innerHTML = "<a style='padding:10px;color:white;font-weight:bold' href='www.google.com'>Google It</a>";}_

Comment: Hey Jarrod Roberson, Nkosi, Olaf, FrankerZ, Sotirios Delimanolis, can you remove your vote down on my post or take it off [hold]. A "-3" is a bit much right out the gate. I removed my extra thought processes/code and edit the title and body, leaving only the basic issue clearly stated.

Answer (score 3):

1. Get the element (you're doing that):

   ```
   var points = document.getElementById("points");
   ```
2. Get the text of the element:

   ```
   var text = points.innerHTML; // or .textContent or .innerText
   ```
3. Convert it to number in any of the various ways you can do that, such as `parseInt`:

   ```
   var num = parseInt(text, 10); // 10 = base 10 (decimal)
   // or
   var num = parseFloat(text);
   // or
   var num = +text;
   // or
   var num = Number(text);       // Just like the unary +
   ```

   [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28994875/157247) goes into detail of the various options (`parseInt`, `parseFloat`, unary `+`, `Number`).

Then `num` contains the number.

You can, of course, combine the steps:

```
var num = +document.getElementById("points").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try everything you first mentioned, but it sounds like it would work. However, I did try the combine steps on the original code (_var points_) and it worked, but simply adding _.innerHTML_ to the end worked.

Answer (score 0):

[`document.getElementById(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns a [DOM Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), you'll have to access a property of that element to get the number. In this case, since you're dealing with a `<span>` element, you can use `.textContent` to get its text content.

Here is an example:

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("points").textContent);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works as well, but simply adding _.innerHTML_ to the end of my original _var_ worked.