# Is it possible to use string functions on numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Can you tell me if it is ok to use string functions on numbers in Javascript? I have a code which needs to do some modifications on string values. Like here:

```
var value = 0;

if( tableRow.find('input').length )
{
    value = tableRow.find('input').val();
}

value = value.replace(/\s/g, '')  // Remove spaces
```

But sometimes value before replace() remains default 0 which is number type. So is it ok to call replace( or other string function ) on the number? It seems it works but I am not sure if all browsers will support it.

**EDIT**: Not it is not possible. My code works fine because it is always string and condition is not skipped. But variables of number type have NOT .string() function.

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log( typeof someInput.value )` or `console.log( typeof $somejQInput.val() )` ?

Comment: Are you sure the returned value is `0` and not `"0"`?

Comment: your code is modifying `String`s, it never modifies `Number`s so there's not a problem

Comment: `.val()` always returns a string.

Comment: @JaromandaX - Not if the `if` condition is false.

Comment: oh yeah - didn't consider that

Answer (score 3):

You can't call `replace` on a number. What you can do is to call it on `value.toString()` or to set `value` initially to `0`

Comment: Yes you are right. Numbers has no .string() function. My code works cause it is always string and conditions is not skipped in my case.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to use string functions on numbers in javascript?

No. Numbers and strings have different methods. Numbers don't have a `replace` method (because it doesn't make sense for numbers, but does make sense for strings).

> But sometimes value before replace() remains default 0 which is number type.

To avoid that, make your default a string as well:

```
var value = "0";
// ---------^-^

if( tableRow.find('input').length )
{
    value = tableRow.find('input').val();
}

value = value.replace(/\s/g, '')  // Remove spaces
```

...or only do the `replace` on the other path, and convert to number on the other path:

```
var value = 0;

if( tableRow.find('input').length )
{
    value = tableRow.find('input').val();
    value = +value.replace(/\s/g, '')  // Remove spaces, convert to number
}
```

(`+` is just one way to convert to number. [You have several options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875), each with pros and cons.)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to use replace on numbers, because there is not such function in the Number class.

Your value propably is a string, (check it with typeof(value) ), that string containing only numbers don't make it a number.

value = 10 it's not the same as value = "10".