# How to get an input value of input type number?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I've got a number field in my form which one can input a score here:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control" name="total_score" id='total_score' value="<?php echo $total_score;?>" >(Please enter a score from 0-100)
```

And before the form is submit, I need to check whether this field is filled. I'd not like to use the ***required*** since I don't want to block the user when they need more time to decide the input score.

I tried to catch the value of total score with:

```
                var score  = document.getElementsById("total_score").value;
                if(score==null){
                    alert("no score");
                }
```

But seems not working. Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: *" I'd not like to use the required since I don't want to block the user when they need more time to decide the input score."* That seems odd, this is exactly what `required` is for. It will only prevent form submission, not tabbing around the fields and such.

Comment: I assume the `getElementsById` is a typo, and your real code has `getElementById` (no `s`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, it sounds wierd. But since I've also got a button for save the form temporarily, which allows the users to leave some fields be blank. This is why I 'd not like to use required for this form.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's really my bad to misuse getElementById with getElementsByName. Thanks for pointing it out! ;)

Answer (score 1):

`value` will never be `null` because it's always a string. You could use

```
var score  = document.getElementsById("total_score").value.trim();
if (!score) {
    alert("no score");
}
```

...since any non-blank string (including `"0"`) will be truthy.

Once you'e determined there's a value there, you can either convert it to number yourself ([my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) has several options) or use the `valueAsNumber` property of the input.

Note: [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) was added in ES2015 so it won't exist in obsolete browsers like IE8 unless you polyfill it.

---

Side note: I assume the `getElementsById` in your question is a typo, and your real code has `getElementById` (no `s`).

Comment: When I print the variable score on the screen, it seems that the system does't even catch that element. :(

Comment: @Lykas - Look in the web console, are you getting some kind of error? (Did you see the note about the error in `getElementById`?)

Comment: Thanks! It's really the typo mistake, I misused with getElementsByName ;(

Comment: @Lykas - Glad that helped. :-) The `null` thing was also an issue (since `"" == null` is `false`).

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder May I clarify one thing? Is `if(!score)` this equal to `if(score=="")` ?

Comment: @Lykas - Not in the general case, but it is if you know `score` is a string. All non-blank strings are *truthy* (they convert to `true` when used as a boolean); a blank string is *falsy* (it converts to `false` when used as a boolean). Just FYI, the falsy values are `""`, `0`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`. All other values (including `"0"`) are truthy.

Answer (score 1):

Lets describe this problem in details. We always need to understand problem the under the hood that we can solve all similar problems.

```
<div class="score-field">
    <label for="total_score">(Please enter a score from 0-100)</label>
    <input 
      type="number"
      id="total_score"
      name="total_score" 
      min="0" 
      max="100" 
      value="<?php echo $total_score;?>">
</div>
```

If we want to grab the value `document.getElementById('total_score').value`. It return a `String` type of value.

```
let value = document.getElementById('total_score').value;
console.log(typeof value) //'String'
```

So a `String` type of value never be `null`

```
let value = '';
console.log(value == null) //false
```

Enough discussion, Right?

Lets solve the problem.

```
const score = parseFloat(document.getElementById('total_score').value);
```

Its convert the value `String` to `Number`.

Suppose

```
parseFloat("100"); // 100
parseFloat(''); //NaN
```

We can check is `value` really a number or not.

```
isNaN(value); // return true or false
```

I think, here is your problem solve.

Full solve:

HTML:

```
<div class="score-field">
        <label for="total_score">(Please enter a score from 0-100</label>
        <input 
          type="number"
          id="total_score"
          name="total_score" 
          min="0" 
          max="100">
</div>
```

JS:

```
const score = parseFloat(document.getElementById("total_score").value);

if(isNaN(score)){
   alert("no score");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
            if(isNaN(parseInt(score))){
                alert("no score");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
// first get the element
let element = document.getElementById('myInput');

// get the value property of the element
console.log(element.value);

//we could do a check the following way:

function change() {
  if (element.value > 100) {
    console.log('value too big');
  }

  if (element.value < 5) {
    console.log('value too small');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value=5 id="myInput" oninput="change()"/>
```