# variable assignment from "any" returns incorrect data type

Tags: angular, typescript

i am serializing/mapping data from httpclient's result as shown below:

```
export class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.bar = 0.00;
    }
    bar: number;
}

fromJson(json: any) : Foo {
    const foo = new Foo();
    foo.bar = json.bar;
    return foo;
}
```

when i write `console.log(typeof foo.bar)`, i get `string` rather than `number`. is this the intended result and i really need to type cast `foo.bar = parseInt(json.bar)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when i write console.log(typeof foo.bar), i get string rather than number. is this the intended result

Yes. TypeScript doesn't insert conversion code for you.

> ...and i really need to type cast foo.bar = parseInt(json.bar)?

That's not a cast¹, but yes, you do need to convert to number if your starting point is not a number (and `parseInt` is one way to do that — [there are several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875), each with pros and cons — if your starting point is a string).

¹ *And in fact, TypeScript doesn't have casts, it has [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), which are similar but different.*

Comment: Add: if you have a `mystring = "14.45"` and you do `var nm = +mystring;` nm will be type `number`

Comment: @JacopoSciampi - That's covered by the "there are several" link (including the pitfalls of doing that -- **all** the built-in ways to do it have pitfalls).

Comment: Thanks @TJ for correcting me regarding `type assertion` and `converting/parsing`, i have also read your answer on the other thread. was a good read. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, but wanted to share a codepen with a little proof of concept:
https://codepen.io/abarrenechea/pen/xQOqdX

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = 0.00;
  }
  bar: number;
}

var foo1 = new Foo();
foo1.bar = "Hello";

var foo2 = new Foo();
foo2.bar = 10;

var foo3 = new Foo();
foo3.bar = true;

document.getElementById("foo1").innerHTML = foo1.bar + " | Type: " + typeof foo1.bar; // this is a string
document.getElementById("foo2").innerHTML = foo2.bar + " | Type: " + typeof foo2.bar; // this is a number
document.getElementById("foo3").innerHTML = foo3.bar + " | Type: " + typeof foo3.bar; // this is a boolean
```

Variables are overriden if you need to maintain the type you should cast first.