# Remove currency symbol from string and convert to a number using a single line in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, aws-lambda

I have a string below that is a price in £, I want to remove the currency symbol and then convert this into a number/price I can use to compare against another value (eg. X >= Y ...)

`£14.50`

I have previously converted strings to numbers used for currency with

`var priceNum = parseFloat(price);`

IDEAL OUTCOME

`14.50` as a number value. Can this be done in a single line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the currency symbol will always be there, just use `substring`:

```
var priceNum = parseFloat(price.substring(1));
```

If it may or may not be there, you could use `replace` to remove it:

```
var priceNum = parseFloat(price.replace(/£/g, ""));
```

Beware that `parseFloat("")` is `0`. If you don't want `0` for an empty input string, you'll need to handle that. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) has a rundown of the various way to convert strings to numbers in JavaScript and what they do in various situations.

Side note: Using JavaScript's standard numbers for currency information is generally not best practice, because if things like the classic `0.1 + 0.2` issue (the result is `0.30000000000000004`, not `0.3`). There are various libraries to help, and [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) is coming to JavaScript as well (it's a Stage 3 proposal at the moment, currently shipping in Chrome). `BigInt` is useful because you can use multiples of your basic currency (for instance, `* 100` for pounds and pence).

Comment: This is great, thanks. How could I add a $ option as well? To detect both £ and $?

Comment: @Gracie - The first one already does because it blindly skips the first character. For the second one, you'd use the regular expression `/[£$]/g` instead.

Answer (score 19):

I found this very helpful

```
var currency = "-$4,400.50";
var number = Number(currency.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,""));
```

[Convert (Currency) String to Float](https://jsfiddle.net/jinglesthula/hdzTy/)

Comment: This works like magic! It safely parses any formatting like `'+1.997  €'`. Heck even something erroneous like `'stack -1.5 overflow'`.

Answer (score 0):

try this number-formatter-npm library. This library is fantastic.

npm i number-formatter-npm

documentation:https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-formatter-npm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try `currency-to-float`:

1. Install the npm package

```bash
npm install currency-to-float
```

2. Use the package to convert price into a number

```js
import currencyToFloat from 'currency-to-float';

const price = '£14.50';

const parsed = currencyToFloat(price);

console.log(parsed); // 14.5
```

Comment: Is this **your** library?