# object HTMLSpanElement showing up on return after initiating typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm writing a typescript to automatically calculate currency exchange rates on different websites, everything seems to be working, except for one part, when the typescript alters the text on the HTML page, it shows "[object HTMLSpanElement]" before the value that was calculated.

```
var USDtoEUR = () => {
    var findUSD = document.querySelectorAll(".usd")[0];
    if (findUSD === null){
        return;
    };
    var EUR = "0.94"; 
    parseInt(EUR);
    parseInt(findUSD);
    var y = findUSD * EUR
    var z = y.toString();
    findUSD.textContent = z;
};

setInterval(USDtoEUR, 300);
```

That's the entirety of my script so far, the selector is a span on the html page. The script returns the value that's needed, but it always has the "[object HTMLSpanElement]" part in front of it. I'm not sure what is causing this.

Comment: What is `findbal`? What is `x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you locate an Element with `document.querySelector(".usd")`, you need to get the text from within it to before sending *that* as input to `parseInt`.

Also note that while parseInt returns an integer or NaN, it doesn't mutate the input.

```js
const EUR_RATE = 0.94;

const USDtoEUR = () => {
  const findUSD = document.querySelector(".usd");
  if (findUSD === null) {
    return;
  };
  const y = parseInt(findUSD.textContent.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,"")) * EUR_RATE
  findUSD.textContent = `€${y}`;
};

setInterval(USDtoEUR, 300);
```

```html
<span class="usd">$1000</span>
```

Comment: Thank you! That cleared it up for me, however now when I execute the function, it returns NaN, how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: I have no idea, because in the above example it does not return NaN

Comment: Would the fact that the span element has a $ sign in the textContent be the reason?

This is the HTML of the span
"<span class="usd">$0.00</span>"

Comment: Yes `parseInt('$0.00')` -> `NaN`

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks for your help! Now I gotta figure out hwo to remove the $ sign from within the textContent!

Comment: I've updated it with String.replace and a regex to remove the currency symbols borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54616643/remove-currency-symbol-from-string-and-convert-to-a-number-using-a-single-line-i