# How to check if value is in preferd format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i have a input field.

Inside this field the user should only enter text in this format

`1+1+2+3`

maximum `1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1` (12x)

How i can check this 
only checking for numbers 
`var isnum = /^\d+$/.test($(this).val());`
will be the half work, but for more i dont know how...

Comment: only single digit ??

Comment: Relying on users to enter data in a specific format is asking for trouble. I'd suggest either using individual input elements for each number, or a masking library to restrict the input options.

Comment: yes only digits and plus-sign and the maximum of entered numbers must be = 12, 6+6 or 3+6+3...

Comment: @MikeR `eval($(this).val()) <= 12`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a quantifier to say how many to accept, so:

```
var isnum = /^\d+(?:\+\d+){0,11}$/.test($(this).val());
```

That says to accept any number of digits at the beginning, optionally followed by 0 to 11 examples of `+` and any number of digits.

Live Example:

```js
function test(str, expect) {
  var result = /^\d+(?:\+\d+){0,11}$/.test(str);
  console.log(str, result, !result === !expect ? "Test:Pass" : "Test:FAIL");
}

test("1", true);
test("1+2+3+4+1234", true);
test("1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1", true);
test("1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1", false);
```

In a comment you've added:

> es only digits and plus-sign and the maximum of entered numbers must be = 12, 6+6 or 3+6+3...

That's a completely different thing, and you can't reasonably test for it with a regular expression (you'd need a ridiculous number of alternatives). Instead, use a regular expression (such as the above) to test the format, then do the sum:

```
if (/*...the format is good...*/) {
    sum = str.split("+").reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b));
    if (sum > 12) {
        // disallow it
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function test(str, expect) {
  var result = /^\d+(?:\+\d+){0,11}$/.test(str);
  if (result) {
    result = str.split("+").reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b)) <= 12;
  }
  console.log(str, result, !result === !expect ? "Test:Pass" : "Test:FAIL");
}

test("1", true);
test("1+2+3+4+1234", false); // sum > 12
test("1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1", true);
test("1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1", false); // too many
test("12345", false); // sum > 12
```

In that I've used `Number(x)` to convert from string to number, but you have a **lot** of options, which I detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875).

Comment: he is talking about the sum ( 12 )

Comment: @PranavCBalan - ***sigh*** :-)

Comment: probably `eval()` can  be use

Comment: @PranavCBalan - Yeah, but I opted for `split` and `reduce`. :-)

Comment: yes, that would be better than eval :) , improper use may cause issues.

Comment: you have to parse string into num

Comment: `sum = str.split("+").reduce((a, b) => a + +b, 0);`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for explaining, one thing, if i enter "12345" it should failed, but i will accept - how i have to change the regex

Comment: @MikeR - With the above, entering `12345` fails (because the sum is > 12). If you mean you want just the regular expression to reject it, what makes it not fit? Is a `+` always required?

Comment: oh sorry, to make it a little complicate. in case entering only 12 it is ok, enter more than 12 is not ok,enter more than 12 in sum of each seperated numbers by plus-sign is also not ok. And we need everytime exactly 12

Comment: @MikeR *"And we need everytime exactly 12"* Well, that's new information. You can easily work out how to change the above to do that, though, surely? `sum > 12` => `sum !== 12`?