# Java script key value pair to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I  am new to javascript. I have an array of data in the format:

```
Toronto, Ontario: 95 
Markham, Ontario: 71
```

I want to convert it to an array of object:

[image] Like this, to be consistent with other functions.

I tried:

```
reportData.fbcity = Object.keys(reportData.city).map((city) => {
    return {
        city: city,
        value: reportData.city[city]
    };
});
```

What I get is:
{city: "Markham, Ontario": "value": 71}

Comment: Expected output is wrong

Comment: `{Toronto, Ontario: 95}` is not a valid object.

Comment: Your  desired format is not valid object, please update proper data

Comment: Yes, but I just want in that format in order to pass it to existing functions.

Comment: Your keys `Toronto` and `Markham` need values

Comment: Explain what you mean with the Array.  That doesn't seem like an Array, it seems like an Object whose key is a city/country.

Comment: @kevin - But since the quoted format is (probably) invalid (and your starting point is also vague), we don't know what you mean. There are at least two different ways to interpret what you've said you want, and at least two ways I can interpret what you say your starting point is.

Comment: @Alex - Well, unless there are in-scope variables with those names. ;-) (Thanks to shorthand properties in ES2015+)

Comment: @MaheerAli - Unless there's an in-scope variable called `Toronto`. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder These data are fetched from backend. No variable called Toronto...

Comment: @kevin - Yes, that was a joke. Please update your question to show us your **actual** starting data. As I said above, it's unclear. I've guessed in my answer, but...

Comment: (Not a very good joke.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated question, I take it that you have this:

```
const start = ["Toronto, Ontario: 95", "Markham, Ontario: 71"];
```

and you want this:

```
result = [
    {"Toronto, Ontario": 95},
    {"Markham, Ontario": 71}
];
```

To do that, you need to split the number at the end of the string off, and then build objects with the two parts of the string. If you know there's only ever one `:`, then:

```
const result = start.map(str => {
    const [city, number] = str.split(":");
    return {
        [city]: +number
    };
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const start = ["Toronto, Ontario: 95", "Markham, Ontario: 71"];
const result = start.map(str => {
    const [city, number] = str.split(":");
    return {
        [city]: +number
    };
});
console.log(result);
```

That uses destructuring to capture the two parts from `split`, then a computed property name to create a property with the city name, and `+` to coerce the number to number from string. (That's just one of your number-to-string options, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) for more options.)

Comment: I was hoping to know some interesting reason to use :)

Comment: @CodeManiac - Nope, there's really no justification and I'm going to remove it. :-) [The spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type) is quite clear about the whitespace being handled.

Answer (score 0):

```
reportData.fbcity = Object.keys(reportData.city).map((city) => {
    return {
        [city]: reportData.city[city]
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `split`

- split with `:` and than build a object
- `+` is used to convert string to number

```js
let data = ["Toronto, Ontario: 95", "Markham, Ontario: 71"];


let op = data.map(val=>{
  let [key,value] = val.split(':')
  return {[key]: +value}
})

console.log(op)
```