# How to turn a string onto a map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to turn a string formatted like that:

```
string = "John:31,Miranda:28"
```

Onto this;

obj = { "John" => 31, "Miranda" => 28 }

I did this :

```
const class = new Map();
array = string.split(",");
```

And obviously I do not know what do with it because after the split I get something like this:

```
["John:31", "Miranda:28"]
```

And I don't know how to turn it onto an object (using the ":" as a arrow)... Maybe I don't need to use the array as an intermediary? Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: what is with the arrows in the object? That is fat arrow syntax..... Do you actually want it to be functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split` to split by comma, and then `map` on the resulting strings to split again by colon, and feed the resulting array of arrays into the `Map` constructor.

For instance, if you want the map keyed by the names, which I suspect you do:

```js
const string = "John:31,Miranda:28"
const map = new Map(string.split(",").map(entry => entry.split(":")));
console.log(map.get("John")); // "31" (a string)
```

If you want the numbers to be *numbers*, not strings, you'll need to convert them:

```js
const string = "John:31,Miranda:28"
const map = new Map(string.split(",").map(entry => {
    const parts = entry.split(":");
    parts[1] = +parts[1];
    return parts;
}));
console.log(map.get("John")); // 31 (a number)
```

[My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) goes into some detail on your options for converting from string to number.

---

If you want the map keyed by value instead (which I suspect you don't, but...), you just have to reverse the order of the inner array entries:

```js
const string = "John:31,Miranda:28"
const map = new Map(string.split(",").map(entry => {
    const [name, num] = entry.split(":");
    return [num, name];
}));
console.log(map.get("31")); // John
```

Comment: It works; but I need to turn the value from a string to an integer... any idea?

Comment: @JeanhDev - Heh, I guessed you might, and *just* updated the answer... :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! such a comprehensive and  complete answer! have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
const data = "John:31,Miranda:28"

const splitData = data.split(',')

const result = splitData.reduce((newObject, item) => {
  const [name, age] = item.split(':')
  return {
    ...newObject,
    [name]: parseInt(age)
  }
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

So split on the commas, loop over it and split on the colon, and build the object.

```js
var myString = "John:31,Miranda:28"
var myObj = myString.split(',').reduce(function (obj, part) {
  var pieces = part.split(':')
  obj[pieces[0]] = pieces[1]
  return obj
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add this here:

- Basically, split string by the comma, then the colon.
- Combine result into a map

```js
const test = "John:31,Miranda:28"; 
console.log(test);
const obj = test.split(/,/).map(item => item.split(/:/));
console.log(obj);
const _map = new Map(obj);
console.log(_map);
console.log(_map.get("John"))
```

[image]