# Number.parseInt of a not alphanumeric string gives a typeof 'number'

Tags: javascript

this is what´s happening

`typeof Number.parseInt('processed')` prints `'number'`.

[image]

---

But if `Number.parseInt('processed')` gives `NaN`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to check the result was parsed successfully, use `isNaN(result)` (`true` = didn't parse anything from the string). See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) listing the various ways to convert from string to number and their various pitfalls/idiosyncrasies.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder... thanks... isNaN works for the use case here...

Answer (score 9):

`Number.parseInt('string')` returns `NaN`, which has a type of `number`.

You can verify it in the browser console:

> typeof NaN === 'number'
>
> true

Here's a [handy guide on how to test against `NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#Testing_against_NaN).

Comment: @Clarity - Welcome to IEEE-754 floating point, you mean. NaN is not a JavaScript invention.

Comment: thanks to @Clarity and all the others for clearing these minute details about the EcmaScript specification...

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` is a value representing Not-A-Number.

#### Steps:

1. `Number.parseInt('processed')` is `NaN`
2. `typeof NaN` is a `number`.

#### Why?

The ECMAScript standard states that Numbers should be IEEE-754 floating point data. This includes `Infinity`, `-Infinity`, and also `NaN`.

#### Other tricky results with NaN:

```
NaN < 1;    // false
NaN > 1;    // false
NaN == NaN; // false
```

#### Testing against NaN:

Use `Number.isNaN()` or `isNaN()` to most clearly determine whether a value is `NaN`.