# Comparing an input value in an if condition

Tags: jquery, html, flask

I'm trying enable/disable an input button with a simple `if` condition in jQuery but somehow the `if` is working but the `else if` won't work. I'm trying to enable the input button in a range between 0 - 40. The button enables when putting in a number above 0 but won't disable when I'm above 40. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);
  
  $('#temp').keyup(function() {
    if ($('#temp').val() > '40') {
      $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);
    } else if ($('#temp').val() > '0') {
      $('#btn').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="/mainpage">
  <div>
    <label>Temperatur in <strong>°C</strong>:</label>
    <input type="number" id="temp" name='temperatur'> </input>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" name="button" value="Weiter">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$("#temp").val()` when it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not compare `string` value like that. Compare number instead like below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);
     
     $('#temp').keyup(function() {
        var temp = parseInt($('#temp').val());
        
        if(temp > 40) {
           $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);
        } else if(temp > 0) {
          $('#btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }

   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Temperatur in <strong>°C</strong>:</label>
<input type="number" id="temp"  name='temperatur'> </input>

<input type="submit"  id="btn" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" name = "button" value="Weiter" >
```

Answer (score 3):

You're doing a **string** comparison with strings of digits, which can be surprising. For instance, `"20" > "5"` is false, because `"5"` is greater than `"2"`.

I suspect that's what's catching you off guard. Convert to number before doing the comparisons:

```
var value = +$("#temp").val();
// −−−−−−−−−^
if (value > 40) {
//          ^−−−−−− no quotes
   $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);
} else if (value > 0) {
// No quotes −−−−−−^
     $('#btn').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

There are lots of different ways to convert strings to numbers. In the above I'm using a unary `+`, but [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) for a full list with pros and cons.

---

I should note that it seems odd to be disabling the input when the value is > 40 but only enabling it if the value is 1-39. Perhaps

```
$("#btn").prop("disabled", +$("#temp").val() > 40);
```

That will disable when the value is > 40, enable when it's <= 40.

Comment: I keep see you everywhere, great engineer!

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because `val()` returns a string, so  you're comparing string values, not integer values. As such you're relying on implicit coercion of the types which can lead to odd behaviour - as you've discovered.

To fix this use numeric values for the condition, which can be achieved by using integer literals and `parseFloat()`. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  let $btn = $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);

  $('#temp').keyup(function() {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    $btn.prop('disabled', value <= 0 || value > 40);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="/mainpage">
  <div>
    <label>Temperatur in <strong>°C</strong>:</label>
    <input type="number" id="temp" name="temperatur" />
    <input type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" name="button" value="Weiter" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: PS, I'd use the `"input"` event on an `input` (to allow for paste etc...), also `this.value` seems cleaner than `$(this).val()`.