# JS read data from file txt to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have file in local server (this same directory). I will have 1000 numbers in file

data.txt

```
123
456
677
```

I'd like to load this data into the table using JS
and create a table

```
let table = [123, 456, 677]
```

Comment: It depends on where your javascript runs, if on backend - one approach, if in browser - another

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a local text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you want to do this on a browser.

To do it, you'd read the file as text via ajax, then parse it into an array by splitting on line breaks, then parse the lines as numbers via `parseInt` or similar.

For example:

```
fetch("data.txt")
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.text();
})
.then(text => {
    table = text.split(/[\r\n]+/)            // Split into lines
                .filter(line => line.trim()) // Remove blank lines
                .map(str => parseInt(str));  // Parse lines to numbers
    // Use table here...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error here
});
```

`parseInt` isn't your only option for parsing the strings, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) for a list of your various options and their pros and cons.

More to explore:

- [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch)
- [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: @DanielWitek - No worries. I had an error in the `split` call which is now fixed above, it should be using `+`, not `*`! :-)

Comment: i will try it, and I got it this:

table =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, NaN]

I need

table = [123, 456, 677]

Comment: @DanielWitek - Did you fix the `split`? Also, to get rid of the `NaN`, I've added a `filter` in the answer.

Comment: I didn't see this patch, I change * to + and I  have now:  [123, 456, 677, NaN]

Comment: when I past +! , I have only this [123]

Comment: ok, its works but how use this table, how to use this table outside of the function

Comment: @DanielWitek - See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)'s answers. :-)

Comment: @DanielWitek - Not at all. Async stuff is weird until you get the hang of it. Happy coding!