# Javascript Function is not giving Arithmetic values in desired field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing simple functionality of arithimatic operators using Javascript in my HTML form. But it is not working. It seems right, but dont know why it is not showing value in desired field. Please have a little look into my following code and guide.

```js
var input = $('[name="ServiceTotalCost"],[name="GrantRequest"],[name="MatchingShare"]'),
  ServiceTotalCost = $('[name="ServiceTotalCost"]'),
  GrantRequest = $('[name="GrantRequest"]'),
  MatchingShare = $('[name="MatchingShare"]');

input.change(function() {
  var ServiceTotalCost = (isNaN(parseInt(ServiceTotalCost.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(ServiceTotalCost.val());
  var GrantRequest = (isNaN(parseInt(GrantRequest.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(GrantRequest.val());

  if (ServiceTotalCost > GrantRequest) {
    Difference = ServiceTotalCost - GrantRequest;
    MatchingShare.val(Difference);
  } else if (GrantRequest >= ServiceTotalCost) {
    PercentAge = (GrantRequest * 20) / 100;
    MatchingShare.val(PercentAge);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <h2>*Support Requried Through Grant</h2><br>
    <div class="form-line">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="ServiceTotalCost" id="ServiceTotalCost" required>
      <label class="form-label">Total cost of the service (Rs.)</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <div class="form-line">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="GrantRequest" max="500000" id="GrantRequest" required>
      <label class="form-label">Amount of grant requested (Rs.)*</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <div class="form-line">
      <input type="number" name="MatchingShare" id="MatchingShare" class="form-control" readonly>
      <label class="form-label">Matching share by the applicant (Rs.)</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any errors in your browser developer tools console?

Comment: @JaromandaX not showing any

Comment: Look again. `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined",`

Comment: @mplungjan What should i do to make it correct ?

Comment: You're overwriting each variable you define holding the jQuery objects in the `change` event handler. They are changed to strings, hence the errors

Comment: using `var ServiceTotalCost` inside the handler means the outer `ServiceTotalCost` is inaccessible

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined

The reason is things like this in the `change` handler:

```
var ServiceTotalCost = (isNaN(parseInt(ServiceTotalCost.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(ServiceTotalCost.val());
```

That creates a **local** `ServiceTotalCost` variable that initially has the value `undefined`, and then in its initializer tries to use it as an object. (I assume you meant to use the `ServiceTotalCost` from outside the function, but the local *shadows* it, making it inaccesible.)

Give your locals different names from the variables the handler closes over that hold the jQuery objects for the fields.

Your code is also falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). By not declaring `Difference` and `PercentAge` before assigning to them, you're creating global variables. Instead, declare them.

Finally, the overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that variables start with a lower case letter, so `difference` rather than `Difference`, etc. (Also, the "A" in `percentage` isn't usually capitalized).

For example:

```js
var input = $('[name="ServiceTotalCost"],[name="GrantRequest"],[name="MatchingShare"]'),
  ServiceTotalCost = $('[name="ServiceTotalCost"]'),
  GrantRequest = $('[name="GrantRequest"]'),
  MatchingShare = $('[name="MatchingShare"]');

input.change(function() {
  var cost = (isNaN(parseInt(ServiceTotalCost.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(ServiceTotalCost.val());
  var request = (isNaN(parseInt(GrantRequest.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(GrantRequest.val());

  if (cost > request) {
    var difference = cost - request;
    MatchingShare.val(difference);
  } else if (request >= cost) {
    var percentage = (request * 20) / 100;
    MatchingShare.val(percentage);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <h2>*Support Requried Through Grant</h2><br>
    <div class="form-line">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="ServiceTotalCost" id="ServiceTotalCost" required>
      <label class="form-label">Total cost of the service (Rs.)</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <div class="form-line">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="GrantRequest" max="500000" id="GrantRequest" required>
      <label class="form-label">Amount of grant requested (Rs.)*</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <div class="form-line">
      <input type="number" name="MatchingShare" id="MatchingShare" class="form-control" readonly>
      <label class="form-label">Matching share by the applicant (Rs.)</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Note that you don't need the conditional operator in lines like this:

```
var cost = (isNaN(parseInt(ServiceTotalCost.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(ServiceTotalCost.val());
```

Since `NaN` and `0` are both falsy values, you can use `||` instead to get the same result:

var cost = parseInt(ServiceTotalCost.val()) || 0;

I should note that `parseInt` may or may not be your best choice for converting to number, though; see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) for a rundown of your choices and their pros and cons.

You may not need to parse at all. On modern browsers, you can get the numeric value from the `valueAsNumber` property. That said, if you need to support older browsers that don't have it, it doesn't help you much:

```
var cost = ServiceTotalCost.prop("valueAsNumber") || parseInt(ServiceTotalCost.val()) || 0;
```

But if you don't have to support browsers without support for `type="number"`, then:

```
var cost = ServiceTotalCost.prop("valueAsNumber");
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I did mean to say something about that, and kinda forgot. :-)

Comment: @mplungjan - I'm not sure what you mean there...? With an `input` (even `input type="number"`), `val` always returns a string.

Comment: ah, I may have been assuming the implementation has a `valHook` to return a number from type=number. So a blank or a string with a number.

Comment: @mplungjan - Even so, `valueAsNumber` can be `NaN` (for instance, in a blank field). Good point about `valHook` though.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness sake. Apart from the already answered scope issue and the poor readability of having the same variable names for object and values, the script can be vastly simplified.

```js
$(".form-control").on("change", function() {
  const serviceTotalCosts = +$("#ServiceTotalCost").val(); // converting to number using unary +
  const grantRequestAmount = +$("#GrantRequest").val();
  let matchingShareAmount = 0;
  if (serviceTotalCosts > grantRequestAmount) {
    matchingShareAmount  = serviceTotalCosts - grantRequestAmount;
  } else if (grantRequestAmount >= serviceTotalCosts) {
    matchingShareAmount = (grantRequestAmount  * 20) / 100; // percentage
  }
  $("#MatchingShare").val(matchingShareAmount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <h2>*Support Requried Through Grant</h2><br>
    <div class="form-line">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="ServiceTotalCost" id="ServiceTotalCost" required>
      <label class="form-label">Total cost of the service (Rs.)</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <div class="form-line">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="GrantRequest" max="500000" id="GrantRequest" required>
      <label class="form-label">Amount of grant requested (Rs.)*</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <div class="form-line">
      <input type="number" name="MatchingShare" id="MatchingShare" class="form-control" readonly>
      <label class="form-label">Matching share by the applicant (Rs.)</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your variable naming is atrocious btw - I'd hate to have to read your code on a daily basis

Comment: @T.J.Crowder see update. Using +str now. We do want 0 when empty

Comment: That should work on browsers that support `type="number"` (and thus won't have non-valid numbers). I'd still belt-and-braces if it were me. :-) But even IE10 had `type="number"`, so...