# Tip calculator keeps returning Nan. How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do my first JS app and unfortunately JS returns NaN value instead of desired amount. I bet solution is quite simple, although I kept trying to resolve problem on my own for past 2 hours and nothing works...

```js
function calculateTip () {
var cost = document.querySelector('.amount').value;
var service = document.querySelector('.service').value;
var people = document.querySelector('.numOfPeo').value;

var tip = (cost * service) / people;

if (cost === "" || service === 0) {
    alert("Please enter values");
  }
  if (people === "" || people <= 1) {
    people = 1;
  }
  document.getElementById('totalTip').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = tip;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', calculateTip);
```

```html
  <div class="container">
      <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
      <div class="descr-1"><p>How Much was your bill?</p></div>
      <div class="input-1 amount"><input type="text" placeholder="Bill Amount in £"></div>
      <div class=descr-2><p>How was your service?</p></div>
      <div class="select"> <select class="service">
          <option disabled selected value="0">Choose an Option</option>
          <option value="30">Extraordinary! - 30%</option>
          <option value="20">Amazing! - 20%</option>
          <option value="15">Good - 15%</option>
          <option value="10">Was Ok - 10%</option>
          <option value="5">Awful! - 5%</option>
      </select></div>
      <div class="descr-3">How many people sharing a bill?</div>
      <div class="people numOfPeo"> <input type="text" placeholder="Number of People"></div>
      <button id="btn">Calculate!</button>
      <div class="total">
          <div id="totalTip">
              <sup>$</sup><span id="tip">0.00</span>
              <small id="each">each</small>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: When you read the `value` property of an element, it returns a string. Convert them to numbers using the unary `+` operator or `parseInt()`.

Comment: Why is '  if (people === "" || people <= 1) {
    people = 1;' after 'var tip = (cost * service) / people;'?

Comment: @Terry - Although in the above, since only `*` and `/` are used, they'll be converted to numbers implicitly. Still, better to be explicit. tomgru23, [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) lists the various different ways to do that.

Comment: transform your inputs to actual numbers from strings (given you get them correctly in the first place) by using `parseFloat` or `parseInt` built-in functions of Javascript. **Initialy the inputs are text, strings they are not numbers which can be added or multiplied so you need to transform them to numbers first else result will be Nan = Not a number**

Answer (score 2):

You just have a small issue with the class, it should be on the inputs and not on the div. 
I have fixed it here, on my jsfiddle:

```
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
  <div class="descr-1"><p>How Much was your bill?</p></div>
  <div class="input-1"><input type="text" placeholder="Bill Amount in £" class="amount"></div>
  <div class=descr-2><p>How was your service?</p></div>
  <div class="select"> <select class="service">
      <option disabled selected value="0">Choose an Option</option>
      <option value="30">Extraordinary! - 30%</option>
      <option value="20">Amazing! - 20%</option>
      <option value="15">Good - 15%</option>
      <option value="10">Was Ok - 10%</option>
      <option value="5">Awful! - 5%</option>
  </select></div>
  <div class="descr-3">How many people sharing a bill?</div>
  <div class="people"> <input type="text" placeholder="Number of People" class="numOfPeo"></div>
  <button id="btn">Calculate!</button>
  <div class="total">
      <div id="totalTip">
          <sup>$</sup><span id="tip">0.00</span>
          <small id="each">each</small>
        </div>
```

and you should move the validation before the calculation of the tip:

```
function calculateTip () {
var cost = document.querySelector('.amount').value;
var service = document.querySelector('.service').value;
var people = document.querySelector('.numOfPeo').value;


if (cost === "" || service === 0) {
    alert("Please enter values");
  }
  if (people === "" || people <= 1) {
    people = 1;
  }
  var tip = cost * service/ people;

  document.getElementById('totalTip').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = tip;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', calculateTip);
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/arielbo/qaf6eygc/13/](http://%20%20%20%20https://jsfiddle.net/arielbo/qaf6eygc/13/)

Answer (score 1):

The first element with the class `amount` in your HTML is a `div`, not an `input`. The `input` is *inside* the `div`. So `cost` is `undefined`, since `div`s don't have a `value`. The same problem occurs with `people`, because again the `.numOfPeo` is on the `div`, not the `input`.

You need to target your inputs. Without changing your HTML, you can use a descendant child selector:

```
var cost = document.querySelector('.amount input').value;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^
var service = document.querySelector('.service').value;
var people = document.querySelector('.numOfPeo input').value;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Live Example:

```js
function calculateTip () {
var cost = document.querySelector('.amount input').value;
var service = document.querySelector('.service').value;
var people = document.querySelector('.numOfPeo input').value;
var tip = (cost * service) / people;

if (cost === "" || service === 0) {
    alert("Please enter values");
  }
  if (people === "" || people <= 1) {
    people = 1;
  }
  document.getElementById('totalTip').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = tip;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', calculateTip);
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
      <div class="descr-1"><p>How Much was your bill?</p></div>
      <div class="input-1 amount"><input type="text" placeholder="Bill Amount in £"></div>
      <div class=descr-2><p>How was your service?</p></div>
      <div class="select"> <select class="service">
          <option disabled selected value="0">Choose an Option</option>
          <option value="30">Extraordinary! - 30%</option>
          <option value="20">Amazing! - 20%</option>
          <option value="15">Good - 15%</option>
          <option value="10">Was Ok - 10%</option>
          <option value="5">Awful! - 5%</option>
      </select></div>
      <div class="descr-3">How many people sharing a bill?</div>
      <div class="people numOfPeo"> <input type="text" placeholder="Number of People"></div>
      <button id="btn">Calculate!</button>
      <div class="total">
          <div id="totalTip">
              <sup>$</sup><span id="tip">0.00</span>
              <small id="each">each</small>
            </div>
  </div>
```

...but I'd probably change the HTML instead.

---

I'd also recommend explicitly converting `cost`, `service`, and `people` to numbers rather than relying on implicit conversion. [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) outlines your various options for doing that and their tradeoffs.

Also note that you need to divide `service` by 100 to make it a percentage ("percent" literally "for each hundred"). Otherwise, these tips are going to be **massive**. ;-)