# Beginner: So what am I doing wrong in the following code? (Something with hoisting??)

Tags: javascript, function

This is for now a very basic calculator, but it won't work, as the title says, something to do with hoisting and declaring the "var a"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Functions exc. 8</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        Input monthly salary: <input type="text" placeholder="invoer" id="value1"><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="calc">Calculate yearly salary</button> <br>
        Output yearly salary:<div id="jaarsalaris"></div>

        <script>
        //calculate the yearly salary
        function calc() {
            var a = document.getElementById("value1").value;
            var calculateMonth = a * 12;
            document.getElementById("jaarsalaris").value= calculateMonth;// + berekeningVktgeld;
        }
        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems (and a couple of other things you probably want to change), but they're not hoisting:

1. You're not *calling* your function. `onclick="calc"` => `onclick="calc()"`. Or better yet, use modern event handling (more below).
2. `div` elements don't have a `value` property. You probably want to assign to `textContent`.

Also:

- Although `a * 12` will work, because of implicit conversion from string to number, I always recommend *explicitly* converting from string to number. (`a` is a string because you got the value from the `value` property of an `input`, which is always a string.) You have [lots of options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875); I'll use `parseFloat` below.
- You've left out the opening `<html>` tag. Technically, [it's optional](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#optional-tags) if you have a `<head>` tag, but I suspect you left it out because you thought the `<!doctype html>` was the start tag. It isn't, they're separate things (`<!doctype html>` is the [doctype preamble](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-doctype)).

Here's an example using [modern event handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) rather than `onxyz`-attribute event handlers. That lets you keep `calc` from being global. The global namespace is **really** crowded and it's easy to have hard-to-diagnose conflicts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Functions exc. 8</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        Input monthly salary: <input type="text" placeholder="invoer" id="value1"><br>
        <button id="btn-calc" type="button">Calculate yearly salary</button> <br>
        Output yearly salary:<div id="jaarsalaris"></div>

        <script>
        // This is a "scoping function"
        (function() {
            document.getElementById("btn-calc").addEventListener("click", calc);
            //calculate the yearly salary
            function calc() {
                var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value1").value);
                var calculateMonth = a * 12;
                document.getElementById("jaarsalaris").textContent =  calculateMonth;// + berekeningVktgeld;
            }
        })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or if your environment supports them (most do these days), use a module:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Functions exc. 8</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        Input monthly salary: <input type="text" placeholder="invoer" id="value1"><br>
        <button id="btn-calc" type="button">Calculate yearly salary</button> <br>
        Output yearly salary:<div id="jaarsalaris"></div>

        <script type="module">
        document.getElementById("btn-calc").addEventListener("click", calc);
        //calculate the yearly salary
        function calc() {
            var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value1").value);
            var calculateMonth = a * 12;
            document.getElementById("jaarsalaris").value= calculateMonth;// + berekeningVktgeld;
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code at the top level of a module is not at global scope (it's at module scope, which is accessible only to code within the module; code *outside* the module can't use what's declared within a module unless it's `export`ed).

Comment: @SMAKSS - Well-spotted. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please refer the below fixed code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Functions exc. 8</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    Input monthly salary: <input type="text" placeholder="invoer" id="value1"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate yearly salary</button> <br>
    Output yearly salary:<div id="jaarsalaris"></div>

    <script>
    //calculate the yearly salary
    function calc() {
        var a = document.getElementById("value1").value;
        var calculateMonth = a * 12;
        document.getElementById("jaarsalaris").innerHTML= calculateMonth;
    }
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The mistakes were onclick was not configures properly and since the output has a div it does not have a value property so you need to access the innerHTML property.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thank you! What if I wanted to change the output from the div to an input textbox? I changed it to this: <input type="text" placeholder = "uitvoer" id="jaarsalaris">. So far that doesn't work.

Comment: If you use input you can set the value property rather than innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Functions exc. 8</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    Input monthly salary: <input type="text" placeholder="invoer" id="value1"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate yearly salary</button> <br>
    Output yearly salary:<div id="jaarsalaris"></div>

    <script>
    //calculate the yearly salary
    function calc() {

        var a = document.getElementById("value1").value;
        var calculateMonth = a * 12;
        document.getElementById("jaarsalaris").innerHTML = calculateMonth;// + berekeningVktgeld;
    }
    
    </script>
</body>
```

Here you need to specific .innerHTML and it will work