# This will not return the "if" statement, even though terms are met

Tags: javascript, html

This code should detect where a number is above 1,000,000,000 and below 9,999,999,999. I try to input numbers between these 2 values, but it still returns the else statement. Where is the problem in this code?

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Checking with RegExp</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Enter a 10 digit number between 1000000000 and 9999999999.</p>
<textarea id="inputnumber"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="submitnumber">Check</button>
<script>
function checknumber() {
var tendigitnum = document.getElementById("inputnumber")
if (tendigitnum >= 1000000000 && tendigitnum <= 9999999999) {
alert("You entered the number" + tendigitnum + ".")
}
else {
alert("The page will refresh. Please enter a valid number.")
location.reload()
}
}
document.getElementById("submitnumber").onclick = checknumber
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you can confirm that input value will be number, then just check the length of the input value... Don't forget to use `.value` after element object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're comparing an HTML element to a number. You want to compare a *number* to a number, by:

1. Using the `.value` property on the element to get the string, and
2. Parsing that string to a number (you have **lots** of different ways to do this depending on your use case; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) for a list of them)

For instance:

```
var tendigitnum = Number(document.getElementById("inputnumber").value);
```

Live Example:

```js
function checknumber() {
  var tendigitnum = Number(document.getElementById("inputnumber").value)
  if (tendigitnum >= 1000000000 && tendigitnum <= 9999999999) {
    alert("You entered the number" + tendigitnum + ".")
  } else {
    alert("The page will refresh. Please enter a valid number.")
    location.reload()
  }
}
document.getElementById("submitnumber").onclick = checknumber
```

```html
<p>Enter a 10 digit number between 1000000000 and 9999999999.</p>
<textarea id="inputnumber"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="submitnumber">Check</button>
```

---

On modern browsers you could use a number input:

```
<input type="number" id="inputnumber">
```

and use its `valueAsNumber` property instead of `value`, since `valueAsNumber` will already be a number. You can even add the range validation to the input. More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number).

Comment: That's it, also consider making the input type "number" instead of textarea, if all you want to do is getting number.

Comment: Thank you @T.J. Crowder , this fixed my problem and my code runs smooth!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value in your element, in your code you are checking element