# How to sum an array of number which contains string in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

My array:

```
const a = [                                       
  {                                               
    "baseFare": "1439.00",                                       
  },  
  {                                               
    "baseFare": "1739.00",                                       
  },    
  {                                               
    "baseFare": "1039.00",                                       
  },                                    
]
```

Note: The number of values in const a will increase or decrease its user decisions ! there may be one or 5 or 7 values in the array !

How to sum all the values and output a single value , and in somecase if its only one value then the out put  should be direct single value !

How to achive this ?

My code :

```
a.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

Comment: You could map first? `a.map(({ baseFare }) => baseFare).reduce(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost there
try this,

```
a.reduce((a, b) => a + (+b.baseFare), 0);

//a is the accumulator , and it start with 0 its an integer
//If you need to access baseFare, then you have to get it from object b.baseFare,
//b.baseFare is a string so you have to convert it to a number (+b.baseFare) is for that
```

if you really need to get it as a floating point number, for ex: 5000, showing as "5000.00" then try this out

```
let sum = a.reduce((a, b) => a + (+b.baseFare), 0);;
sum = sum.toFixed(2); //"4217.00"
```

Comment: Working like charm, as the numbers are in float how to sum all including the float values ?

Comment: It will preserve the floating numbers as well, if you put `1439.55` then you will see the out  put is a float number

Answer (score 1):

Just loop, converting the strings to numbers as you go:

```
let result = 0;
for (const entry of a) {
    result += +entry.baseFare;
}
```

Or with destructuring:

```
let result = 0;
for (const {baseFare} of a) {
//         ^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− destructuring
    result += +baseFare;
}
```

That unary `+` is just one way to convert from string to number. I go into all your options in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875).