# sort array of objects with null values javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I need to sort the following array of objects:

```
let data = [{
    "data": {
        "date_entered": "2021-02-18",
        "order": "2",
    },
},
{
    "data": {
        "date_entered": "2021-02-18",
        "order": "1",
    }
},
{
    "data": {
        "date_entered": "2021-02-15",
        "order": "",
    },
},
{
    "data": {
        "date_entered": "2021-02-18",
        "order": "",
    },
}
];
```

It firstly needs to sort by the order value and then sort by the date_entered, this is the code that i have written so far, but it seems to display the data3 data4 first instead of data2, data1, data4, data3

```
return function (a, b) {
        return (
            parseInt(a.data.order) - parseInt(b.data.order) ||
            new Date(b.data.date_entered).getTime() -
                new Date(a.data.date_entered).getTime()
        );
    };
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? would greatly appreciate any help :)

Comment: where is the connection to a `null` value as mentioned with the topic?

Comment: where do you want the `''` values to go?

Comment: @PeterSeliger He means null string, i.e. empty string.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I just want the OP to precisely formulate the topic for others who want to contribute in solving the OP's task and who can not make the connection.

Comment: *"but it seems to display the data3 data4 first instead of data2, data1, data4, data3"* Yes. As it says in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) I [pointed you at before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66276804/sort-array-of-objects-javascript-by-values#comment117173774_66276804), `parseInt("")` returns `NaN`. If you want to handle them specially, you'll need to do that explicitly. For instance:

Comment: `(a, b) => { const avalue = a.data.order === "" ? Infinity : parseInt(a.data.order); const bvalue = b.data.order === "" ? Infinity : parseInt(b.data.order); return a - b; }` or similar.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, `parseInt` is not necessary.

Comment: Hi! I guess you simply need to order values by `order`

    `data.sort((a, b) => {
      return (b.data.order !== '') - (a.data.order !== '') || a.data.order - b.data.order;
    });`

Comment: Oh okay, sorry yes i meant empty string

Comment: The main point is that im trying to firstly sorty by order if order is null sort by date_entered

Comment: @AdriSolid I would like to sort by the order first and then if order is empty sort by date_entered

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this works nicely but i would like to sort the date_entered by DESC :/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `return (
    avalue - bvalue ||
    new Date(b.attributes.publication_date).getTime() -
     new Date(a.attributes.publication_date).getTime()
   );` @T.J.Crowder is this fine?

Comment: @amature - That should do it, yes. :-) For *descending* you may want to swap those around, though: `bvalue - avalue`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks a ton!