# How to convert a decimal (base 10) to 32-bit unsigned integer?

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-manipulation, 32-bit

How to convert a decimal (base 10) to 32-bit unsigned integer?

Example:

If `n = 9` (base 10), how to convert it to something like: `00000000000000000000000000001001` (base 2)?

Answer (score 3):

Let's be clear that when you're talking about number bases, you're talking about **textual representations** (which code will see as strings). Numbers don't have number bases, they're just numbers *(but more on this below)*. A number base is a way of representing a number with a series of digits (text). So `n = 9` isn't base 10 or base 36 or base 2, it's just a number. (The number literal is in base 10, but the resulting number has no concept of that.)

You have a couple of options:

### Built in methods

The number type's [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) accepts a radix (base) to use, valid values are 2 through 36. And the string [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) method lets you pad the start of a string so the string is the desired number of characters, specifying the padding character. So:

```js
const n = 9;
const binaryText = n.toString(2).padStart(32, "0");
console.log(binaryText);
```

**If** your starting point is text (e.g., `"9"` rather than `9`), you'd parse that first. [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) has a full rundown of your number parsing options, but for instance:

```js
const decimalText = "9";
const binaryText = (+decimalText).toString(2).padStart(32, "0");
console.log(binaryText);
```

### Bit manipulation

*"Numbers don't have number bases, they're just numbers"* is true in the abstract, but at the bits-in-memory level, the bits are naturally assigned meaning. In fact, JavaScript's number type is an implementation of IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point.

That wouldn't help us except that JavaScript's bitwise `&` and `|` operators are defined in terms of 32-bit binary integers (even though numbers aren't 32-bit binary integers, they're 64-bit floating point). that means we could *also* implement the above by testing bits using `&`:

```js
const n = 9;
let binaryText = "";
for (let bit = 1; bit < 65536; bit *= 2) {
    binaryText = (n & bit ? "1" : "0") + binaryText;
}
console.log(binaryText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping u guys have already practiced javascript in `leetcode` using `andygala playlists`

```
function flippingBits(n){
    n = n.toString(2).padStart(32, "0");
    n=(n.split(''))
    for(let i=0;i<32;i++){ 
        (n[i]==='1')? n[i]='0': n[i]='1';
    }
    n=n.join('')
    let n=parseInt(n,2)
    return n;
}
console.log(flippingBits(9))
```