# Javascript: confusion on using Logical NOT ! Operator

Tags: javascript

I am slightly confused on the logical NOT operator in Javascript (`!`). From my understanding, this is mainly used to "inverse" a boolean value. For example, if an expected output of a boolean is true, putting this in front would turn it to false, and vice versa.

In my below code, I created a function allowing user to input a lower and upper integer, and the function would generate a random number between this range. If, however, the user inputs a string instead of an integer, it will prompt the user to enter an integer instead.

I am using isNaN to check if user's input is an integer, and using logical NOT operator in front of it to inverse the result.

In my `if` condition, if I check `isNaN` for `lower` `&&` `isNaN` for `upper` are both not a number, this program seems to work correctly. However, if I use `||`, it doesn't work as expected, as shown in my code below.

Why is this so? By using OR operator, I am saying if *either* upper or lower is NaN, then prompt the user to enter a valid integer. Why is it a `&&` and not a `||` when only one condition needs to be true?

```js
const getNumber = function(lower, upper) {
  if ( !isNaN(lower) || !isNaN(upper) ) {
  const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
  return number;
  } else {
  alert("Please enter a valid integer.");
  }
};

// Call the function and pass it different values
console.log( getNumber('six',5) );
```

Comment: NaN does not check if a string is a number. You have to parse it first. Then, the parsing result may be NaN if it could not be parsed

Comment: `console.log(isNaN("six"), isNaN(5))`

Comment: @Random - `isNaN` will use implicit string->number parsing if you pass it a string. (In contrast, `Number.isNaN` won't.)

Comment: If you want to use `OR` you need to remove the `NOT` - Using `isNan` here is somewhat of a double negative situation, so you either want x AND y are both NOT isNan, or x OR y isNan

Answer (score 3):

It's not the `!` operator that's the problem, it's `||`. `if ( !isNaN(lower) || !isNaN(upper) ) {` says (roughly) "if `lower` is a number **or** `upper` is a number". But you don't wan to say "or" there, because you want them *both* to be numbers.

So either use use `&&` (and):

```
if ( !isNaN(lower) && !isNaN(upper) ) {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
    return number;
} else {
    alert("Please enter a valid integer.");
}
```

or reverse the content of your `if` and `else` blocks and use `||` without `!`:

```
if ( isNaN(lower) || isNaN(upper) ) {
    alert("Please enter a valid integer.");
} else {
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
    return number;
}
```

---

Side note: You're using implicit string-to-number parsing in your code. I recommend doing it on purpose. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) goes into your various options for parsing numbers and their pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

By using `OR`, you are checking that at least one value should not be NaN.

```js
let a = !isNaN(lower);
let b = !isNaN(upper);
```

`a` and `b` can be either `true` or `false`. When you use `||`, you are telling that at least one of this values should be `true`. If you check [Truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Binary_operations), you will see that OR will be true for this combitations of `a` and `b`:

- `a == true`, `b == true`
- `a == false`, `b == true`
- `a == true`, `b == false`

What you want is to check that `a == true` and `b == true` simultaneously - so you have to use `AND` (`&&`) which will evaluate to true if and only if `a == true` and `b == true`.