# Js NaN or Undefined element with Math.pow

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, nan

HTML + JavaScript beginner here.

I'm trying to getElementById, a number in my case. I can only achieve NaN, Undefined or some strange text about an object.

I want the element's number and return it with the power of 2. 144.
Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript Test</title>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <p id="number">12</p>
    <button id="button1" onclick="calcSquare()">Click here!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

---

```
function calcSquare() {
  var a = document.getElementById('number').value;
  var b = 2;
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = (Math.pow(a, b));
  }
```

Comment: @blurfus - `a` is `undefined`, `p` elements don't have a `value` property. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `id="numer"` element is a `p`, not an `input` or a `select`, so it doesn't have a `value` property. You could use its `textContent` property, which gives you the text of its content:

```
var a = document.getElementById('number').textContent;
```

Or alternatively use an `input type="text"` instead, so it has a `.value`.

Whether you use `textContent` or `value`, you'll always get a string. You could rely on `Math.pow` to implicitly convert that to number, but I generally find it's best to convert on purpose. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) goes into your various options for that.

I also recommend **not** using `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers. Instead, hook up the event via modern mechanisms like `addEventListener`. That way, the handler doesn't have to be a global function.

(There's also no need for the `()` around `Math.pow(a, b)`.)

Here's an example using a `contenteditable` `p` element:

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function calcSquare() {
    const el = document.getElementById("number");
    const a = +el.textContent;
    const b = 2;
    el.textContent = Math.pow(a, b);
});
```

```html
<p id="number" contenteditable>12</p>
<button id="button1">Click here!</button>
```

In that I've used `const` rather than `var`. There's basically no place for `var` in modern JavaScript programming.

Comment: This was an amazing help. I researched into everything you explained and found it valuable. Everything works! Thank you.