# Show the average of the 1-digit numbers entered

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the following exercise:

> Enter N number of numbers by prompt. Show the average of the 1-digit numbers entered. End the program with the word “exit"/"salir”.

I also have to do the average calculation with a function. Here's what I have:

```js
let i;
var sum = 0;
var avg = 0;

var average = function(i) {
    sum = sum + i;
    avg = sum/(i+1);
}

do {
    i = prompt("Ingrese un numero: ");
    if ((i < 10) && (i > -10)) {
        average(i);
    }
} while (i !== "salir");

alert(`el promedio de los numeros de un solo digito es: ${avg}`);
```

I tried limiting the program by stating that the average function will only be executed for one digit numbers, but the problem is that this is giving me the **total average** of all the numbers entered not the average of only the 1 digit numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've succeeded in avoiding including multi-digit numbers from the sum and average. The problem isn't in that, it's here:

```
avg = sum/(i+1);
```

That's not how averages work. An average is the sum divided by *how many* values went into making that sum. (The number of numbers you added to `sum`.)

Keep track of how many numbers you added to `sum`, and use that count to calculate the average.

---

Side note: A couple of notes on the code, just for what they're worth:

- Your code is currently relying on implicit conversion from string (what the user types in) to number (what you use with `sum`). Although it works in this example, I strongly recommend doing the conversion explicitly. [My other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) (also on SO) lists your various options for doing that.
- You've used both `let` and `var` in your code. I suggest never using `var`, it has no place anymore in modern JavaScript. Use `let` if you need to let the variable's value change (as with `sum`), and `const` when you don't.
- You're missing one `;` (after the assignment statement assigning to `average`). (You can rely on Automatic Semicolon Insertion if you like [I don't recommend relying on it, but some others do], but whichever way you go, it's best to know the rules and then consistently do or don't include your `;`.)
- I suggest declaring your variables in the *innermost* scope you can declare them in. There's no reason for `i` to be global in your code, just make it local to the `do-while` loop body.
- Obviously in a very simple exercise like this it's mostly fine, but I recommend not getting used to `prompt` and `alert`, they're relics from the 1990s and behave in very unusual (and sometimes problematic) ways compared to most functions in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the typo fix @0stone0!

Comment: Thank you very much for all of these tips, will keep those in mind!

Answer (score 0):

```
var i;
var sum = 0;
var avg = 0;

var average = function(num) {
    sum = sum + num;
    i+=1
    avg = sum/i;
}
var ans;
do {
    ans = prompt("Ingrese un numero: ");
    if ((ans < 10) && (ans > -10)) {
        average(ans);
    }
} while (ans !== "salir");

alert(`el promedio de los numeros de un solo digito es: ${avg}`);
```

Should remove this but will leave it here for any future visitors.

Comment: That code uses `i` (but removes its declaration) for two completely different things. It won't correctly calculate an average, because `i` is overwritten by the code in the `do-while` loop.

Comment: Separately, I don't recommend doing the work for someone when they are clearly asking a homework/assignment question. Just explain what they've done wrong and how they can do it right. See [*How do I ask and answer homework questions?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: I agree with mister Crowder, thanks both for the help.