# Enter less than or equal value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to given alert to the user, if user enter more than input variable value.

problem statement:
`Max_ava_water = 300`

if user enter a 6 also it is showing 'Enter less or Equal values'.

```js
var Max_ava_water = 300
$('#input_rd').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val() > Max_ava_water) {
    console.log("Enter less or Equal values")
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="value" id="input_rd" />
```

Comment: about function name, I should be use the  function name  using onfocusout event

Comment: The snippet does not produce the error and appears to work fine...?

Comment: With same snippet also I got errors.

Comment: for me this input value are useful for other calculation

Comment: `$(this).val()` is a string, so "6" is > "3"

Answer (score 3):

You're checking on every `keyup` event, which is too soon — the user could be trying to type 600, which starts with 6, which is less than 100. (Sorry, that comment was when I'd misread your `>` as `<`. But the basic idea still applies.)

Instead, check when the field loses focus (`blur`) or when they try to confirm the value in some other way.

I'd strongly suggest **not** clearing the field when the value is too low. Instead, let them edit the value (maybe they just missed out a `0` at the end).

```js
const Max_ava_water = 300;
// Using `blur` event
$('#input_rd').on("blur", function() {
    // Explicit conversion
    const value = this.value ? parseInt(this.value, 10) : NaN;
    // Note that `NaN` is never `>` anything
    if (value > Max_ava_water) {
        console.log("Enter less or Equal values")
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="input_rd" />
```

Also note that `type="value"` is invalid for [`input` fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input). You could use `type="number"` as I did above to trigger the browser's standard handling for number fields, perhaps with `min` and `max` to do range checking.

---

Side note: `val` returns a string (or `undefined` if you call it on an empty jQuery set, but you aren't). Your expression relies on `>` to implicitly convert that to a number. `>` does do that, but often it's better to do the conversion intentionally, not least because the rules for implicit conversion might not be the rules you want to apply (`""` converts to `0`, for instance). My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) describes your various options and their pros and cons.

Comment: Also note: Watch focus/blur and alert

Comment: how about function name, it is important for me  using the function for further calculation part

Comment: @mplungjan - I missed it was originally an `alert` because you changed it in the snippet. I suggest not doing that.

Comment: @SrinuvasBathula - Then put it in a function. That's not what you asked about, but your course or book should cover writing reusable functions.

Comment: I tried with user answer, Still I got same results.

Comment: @SrinuvasBathula - What input are you providing? What results are you seeing? What results do you expect instead?

Comment: Thank you, I got results.

Comment: showing results  within a field like 'NaN', some other values after click on on alert.but I have to stop  further process when its is more than a Max_ava_water.