# How to check if number is correct 16x based value?

Tags: javascript

For examle I need to check string `'69S0'` - is it correct a 16x based number. I do not need to parse just check `true` or `false`.
So, what is an effcient way to do this?

Comment: I mean, if you only need to check within a very limited range (say, < 10000), you could build a `Set` containing the string version in standard decimal form of every multiple of 16, and then when you needed to check the string you could see if it's in the set, but...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder actually parseInt('0cb41',16) return nuber 69 (but its not). So parsing can't answer is it correct number.

Comment: Read the [answer I pointed you to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875). :-) But just for what it's worth, `parseInt('0cb41',16)` returns 52033 (decimal), not 69.

Comment: `is16 = s => parseInt(s, 16).toString(16) === (s.toString().replace(/^0+/, '').toLowerCase() || '0');`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, not '0cb41' my mistake. But parseInt('69S0',16) return 69.

Comment: @FFire - `parseInt('69S0',16)` returns 105, not 69, but yes `parseInt` will just stop when it hits an invalid digit (`S` in that case). The answer linked above talks about that and offers alternatives.

Comment: Ah, "16x based number" => "base 16 number"! (E.g., hexadecimal.) I'm sorry, I thought you meant "multiple of 16".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check to see if the string contains any invalid digits. The valid digits are `0-9` and `ABCDEF`, so:

```
if (/^[0-9a-f]+$/i.test(theString)) {
    // yes, valid hex
} else {
    // not valid hex
}
```

(That checks that all the characters are valid, beginning to end; alternatively, you could check if it has any *invalid* characters by using `if (!/[^0-9a-f]/.test(theString))` — the regular expression is "not 0-9a-f" and then we use `!` on the result of `test`.)

Alternatively, you could parse the string using the `Number` function (note this logic is the other way around):

```
if (isNaN(Number("0x" + theString)) {
    // not valid hex
} else {
    // yes, valid hex
}
```

That works because `Number` accepts certain number base prefixes (`0x` = hex, `0b` = binary, and `0o` = octal), and returns `NaN` if the entire string isn't a valid number using that number base. (And unlike `Number("")`, which returns `0`, `Number("0x")` returns `NaN`, so it'll work if `theString` is blank, too.)

---

In comments you mentioned that you couldn't rely on `parseInt`, and you're right: Instead of throwing an error or returning `NaN` if there's an invalid digit, `parseInt` just stops parsing and returns what it found at the beginning of the string. (Details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875).)

Comment: isNaN(Number("0x" + theString)) is what I'm looking for