# Creating JS Array from all Values of html .class

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to gather all text values of my class `.amount` into one array.

I know I can get the value of the first element with the class .amount using:

```
const myArray = document.getElementsByClassName('amount')[0].innerHTML;
```

But I want to get all values of all elements using `.amount`

My final goal is to build the sum of all values using this code:

```
function getArraySum(a){
    const total=0;
    for(const i in a) { 
        total += a[i];
    }
    return total;
}

console.log(getArraySum(myArray));
```

I am very new to JS and also open for other approaches.

Comment: Share your HTML code too. What exactly the text in 'amount'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My final goal is to build the sum of all values using this code:

Some notes:

- That code uses `for-in`, which isn't the correct way to loop through an array or other iterable (it's for looping through object properties). For arrays/iterables, you want [`for-of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). (Not supported in obsolete browsers like IE11.)
- You don't need an array for this, the result of calling `getElementsByClassName("amount")` (or `querySelectorAll(".amount")`) is [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols).
- You've said "sum" which is a mathematical operation, so you'll need to convert the text you're getting from the DOM to a number. You have lots of options for doing that, I go through them in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875).
- I'd use `textContent` rather than `innerHTML`, since you probably don't want tag markup.
- You can't declare `total` as `const`, since you're adding to it (modifying its value).

With all that in mind:

```
function getArraySum(iterable) {
    let total = 0;
    for (const element of iterable) { 
        total += +element.textContent;
    }
    return total;
}

console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("amount));
```

But if you want to get an array of numbers first, you can do it using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with its mapping callback:

```
function getArraySum(iterable) {
    let total = 0;
    for (const value of iterable) { 
        total += value;
    }
    return total;
}

const theArray = Array.from(
    document.getElementsByClassName("amount"),
    element => +element.textContent
);
console.log(getArraySum(theArray));
```

Then

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer and all explanations!!