# Javascript .replace() method failing replacing ".&ndash;" with ".00"

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a page displaying a price with `.&ndash;` instead of decimals `.00`:

`<span id="product_price">123.&ndash;</span>`

**I am trying to switch its ending from ".–" to ".00"** (or to nothing) in order to dynamically build the URL of a PayPal (unregistered) payment button, and cannot understand **why Javascript's .replace() method fails replacing the `.&ndash;`**.

Although the source code of the page shows the price is correctly written with the `.&ndash;` in the `<span>`, the `console.log(amount);` prints the amount with a `-` instead of the character entity:

```
var amount = jQuery("span#product_price").html();
console.log(amount);
amount = amount.toString(); // just to be sure
amount.replace('.&ndash;','.00');
```

Hence, I also tried
`amount.replace('.-','.00');`

and `var amount = jQuery("span#product_price").html().replace('.&ndash;','.00');`

Nothing works.
What I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Strings are immutable. Please assign the output of the replace to a new string and use that

Comment: `replace` **returns** the new string with the characters replaced. (Strings are immutable.) Also: The return value of the jQuery `html` function is **always** a string unless you call it on a jQuery set that has no elements in it (in which case it's `undefined`, and trying to call `.toString()` on `undefined` will raise an error). Also, there's no point in the `span` part of `span#product_price` unless you have a **very** unusual situation. IDs are unique, just use the ID.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Thank you for mentioning the immutability of strings. I tried assigning the output of the replace to a new string: `var product_price = jQuery("#product_price").html();
    var amount = product_price.replace('.&ndash;','.00');`. It still doesn't work. Obviously I'm still missing something. Can someone provide an example of what the code should look like?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder : Thank you. I was aware that id are unique but hoped it would fasten finding the element but seems that I was wrong in this regard. Adding the nature of the element (e.g. span) sometimes help me when I have to read the code again after several months.

Comment: What's funny is that parseFloat() (i.e. converting to floating point number) works perfectly at removing the `.&ndash;`: `var amount = parseFloat(jQuery("#product_price").html());`

Comment: @OuzoPower - With jQuery, `$("#id")` is **dramatically** faster than `$("span#id")` though in practice while it's a bit absolute improvement, you'll probably never notice it because the latter is fast *enough*. The reason is that when jQuery sees `#id`, it optimizes that to a call to `getElementById`, which is almost as fast as a variable lookup. But it can't do that for `span#id`, so it uses `querySelectorAll` instead, which is slower (but again, it's not likely to matter).

Comment: @OuzoPower - On `parseFloat`: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) for why. Basically, `parseFloat` doesn't convert the entire string, it just converts the first part and stops at the first invalid character. So `parseFloat("12.&ndash;")` is just like `parseFloat("12.")` because `parseFloat` will stop when it sees the `&`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Thank you very much for your two last comments. It is always interesting to understand what happens behind the scenes, why a selector is better than another, a.s.o. Also useful was to learn that `parseFloat()` stops at the first invalid character ; this makes it very useful to parse numbers followed by a unit of measurement.