# Passing parameters with comma values (European decimal format)

Tags: javascript, cypress, number-formatting

I have written a reusable function in Cypress:

```js
fill_prices_ht_nt(until, AP, GP, AP_NT, new_bonus){
        this.add_range().click({force:true})
        this.range_until().type(until)
        this.ap().type(AP)
        this.gp().type(GP)
        this.ap_nt().type(AP_NT)
        this.new_bonus().type(new_bonus)
```

Now I want to use that function to type in values, but unfortunately I need to type in decimal values in European format (with comma instead of periods), like e.g. "9,35" or "6,47"

```js
        pmmt.fill_prices_ht_nt(99999, 10, 9,35, 6,47, 100)
```

This is of course not working as Cypress/JS treats every comma as a separator.

Is there a somewhat easy workaround to this problem? Otherwise I will have to dump the reusable function and hard-code the values.

Comment: *"I need to type in decimal values in European format"* Why? If the syntax needs a dot as a decimal separator then use a dot.

Comment: Because when I type ```6.47``` in the field on the website I am testing it is treated like ```647```

Comment: You either want raw input which are strings or already parsed data which are floats with a dot, never floats with a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one more option, using [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#using_locales)

```js
fill_prices_ht_nt(until, AP, GP, AP_NT, new_bonus) {
  this.add_range().click({force:true})
  this.range_until().type(until)
  this.ap().type(AP.toLocaleString('de-DE'))  
  this.gp().type(GP.toLocaleString('de-DE'))   // AP.toLocaleString('de-DE') = 9,35
  this.ap_nt().type(AP_NT.toLocaleString('de-DE'))
  this.new_bonus().type(new_bonus.toLocaleString('de-DE'))
```

In the test, pass with decimal and it will be converted as you `.type()`

```js
pmmt.fill_prices_ht_nt(99999, 10, 9.35, 6.47, 100)
```

---

Or, you can add a method to set the format if you have other locale's to handle

```js
set_number_format(number_format) {
  this.number_format = number_format
}

fill_prices_ht_nt(until, AP, GP, AP_NT, new_bonus) {
  this.add_range().click({force:true})
  this.range_until().type(until)
  this.ap().type(AP.toLocaleString(this.number_format))  
  this.gp().type(GP.toLocaleString(this.number_format))
  this.ap_nt().type(AP_NT.toLocaleString(this.number_format))
  this.new_bonus().type(new_bonus.toLocaleString(this.number_format))
```

In the test,

```js
pmmt.set_number_format('de-DE')
pmmt.fill_prices_ht_nt(99999, 10, 9.35, 6.47, 100)
...
pmmt.set_number_format('en-IN')
pmmt.fill_prices_ht_nt(99999, 10, 9.35, 6.47, 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can supply the numbers as strings, like this:

```
pmmt.fill_prices_ht_nt("99999", "10", "9,35", "6,47", "100")
```

Then write a utility function to convert those strings to numbers:

```
function toNumber(val) {
    if (typeof val !== "string") {
        return val;
    }
    return +val.replace(/,/g, ".");
}
```

(Unary `+` is just one way to do string-to-number conversion, I provide a list with pros and const in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875).)

And use it in your function:

```
fill_prices_ht_nt(until, AP, GP, AP_NT, new_bonus) {
    until = toNumber(until);
    AP = toNumber(AP);
    GP = toNumber(GP);
    AP_NT = toNumber(AP_NT);
    new_bonus = toNumber(new_bonus);
    this.add_range().click({force:true});
    this.range_until().type(until);
    this.ap().type(AP);
    this.gp().type(GP);
    this.ap_nt().type(AP_NT);
    this.new_bonus().type(new_bonus);
}
```

If you don't mind using a temporary array, you can use destructuring to do the conversions all in one:

```
function toNumberList(...vals) {
    return vals.map(toNumber);
}
```

Then using it:

```
fill_prices_ht_nt(until, AP, GP, AP_NT, new_bonus) {
    [until, AP, GP, AP_NT, new_bonus] = toNumberList(until, AP, GP, AP_NT, new_bonus);
    this.add_range().click({force:true});
    this.range_until().type(until);
    this.ap().type(AP);
    this.gp().type(GP);
    this.ap_nt().type(AP_NT);
    this.new_bonus().type(new_bonus);
}
```

That assumes an ES2015+ environment (because it uses destructuring).

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely use the function toNumberList in the future as I often need to convert decimal values from comma to periods!

Answer (score 1):

How about you just use the `pmmt.fill_prices_ht_nt` with all numbers as strings.

```js
 pmmt.fill_prices_ht_nt('99999', '10', '9,35', '6,47', '100')
```

Because when I see the cypress [type](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#Syntax), in syntax it says, `type` accepts these two formats:

```js
.type(text)
.type(text, options)
```