# Javascript Converting an incoming buffer as a string to a buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

const stringArray = ['0x00','0x3c','0xbc]

to

const array = [0x00,0x3c,0bc]

var buf = new Buffer.from(array)

How should I go about using the buffers in the string above as buffers?

Comment: You may want to use something like this: `Buffer.from(['0x00','0x3c','0xbc'].map(e => +e)));`

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have an array of strings where the strings are byte values written as hexadecimal strings. So you need to:

- Convert each hex string to a byte; that's easily done with `parseInt(str, 16)` (the 16 being hexadecimal). `parseInt` will allow the `0x` prefix. Or you could use `+str` or `Number(str)` since the prefix is there to tell them what number base to use. (More about various ways to convert strings to numbers in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875).)
- Create a buffer and fill it in with the bytes.

If the array isn't massive and you can happily create a temporary array, use `map` and `Buffer.from`:

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(theArray.map(str => +str)));
```

If you want to avoid any unnecessary intermediate arrays, I'm surprised not to see any variant of `Buffer.from` that allows mapping, so we have to do those things separately:

```
const buffer = Buffer.alloc(theArray.length);
for (let index = 0; index < theArray.length; ++index) {
    buffer[index] = +theArray[index];
}
```