# Each digit differs from the next one by 1

Tags: javascript

Script has to work this way:

```
isJumping(9) === 'JUMPING'
```

This is a one digit number

```
isJumping(79) === 'NOT JUMPING'
```

Neighboring digits do not differ by 1

```
isJumping(23454) === 'JUMPING'
```

Neighboring digits differ by 1

I have:

```js
function isJumping(number) {
    let str = number.toString();
    for (let i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(str[i+1]) - Math.abs(str[i]) == 1){
            return 'JUMPING';
        }
    }
    return 'NOT JUMPING';
}
console.log(isJumping(345));
```

Help please, where is mistake?

Comment: You're not handling the single digit case, nor the case if the number goes down.

Comment: A clumsy way would be `if (Math.abs(Math.abs(str[i+1]) - Math.abs(str[i])) == 1)`. Right now you are using `Math.abs()` to convert digits to numbers. Also, indexing is off, you start from 1, which is good, but then you should compare `[i]` and `[i-1]`. And the usual mismatch: you can say "JUMPING", only at the end. So you should check for `!==1`, and return "NOT JUMPING" inside the loop, and "JUMPING" after. That would handle the 1-digit case too.

Comment: now it doesn't throw errors only because the off index gets evaluated as undefined and the subraction returns false. But it's odd to read in terms of how it fulfills a given logic

Comment: What's your preferred output for `11`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the characters and early return with `"NOT JUMPING"` if the condition is violated & if the condition is never violated return `"JUMPING"`.

```js
function isJumping(num) {
  const strNum = String(Math.abs(num));

  for (let i = 0; i < strNum.length - 1; i++) {
    if (Math.abs(strNum[i] - strNum[i + 1]) > 1) {
      // replace `> 1` with `!== 1`, if diff 0 is not valid!
      return "NOT JUMPING";
    }
  }

  return "JUMPING";
}

console.log(isJumping(9));
console.log(isJumping(79));
console.log(isJumping(23454));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues:

1. You're not handling single digits.
2. You're returning too early. You're returning the **first** time you see a difference of `1` between digits, but you don't know that subsequent differences will also be `1`.
3. You're not checking the difference between the first and second digits, and you're going past the end of the string.
4. You're using `Math.abs` as a means of converting digits to numbers.

Instead (see comments):

```js
function isJumping(number) {
    let str = number.toString();
    for (let i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
        // Convert to number, do the difference, then
        // use Math.abs to make -1 into 1 if necessary
        if (Math.abs(+str[i] - str[i-1]) !== 1) {
            // Found a difference != 1, so we're not jumping
            return "NOT JUMPING";
        }
    }
    // Never found a difference != 1, so we're jumping
    return "JUMPING";
}
console.log(isJumping(345));    // JUMPING
console.log(isJumping(9));      // JUMPING
console.log(isJumping(79));     // NOT JUMPING
console.log(isJumping(23454));  // JUMPING
```

In that, I use `+str[i]` to convert `str[i]` to number and implicitly convert `str[i-1]` to number via the `-` operator, but there are lots of ways to convert strings to numbers (I list them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875)), pick the one that makes sense for your use case.

You might also need to allow for negative numbers (`isJumping(-23)`).

Answer (score 0):

> A clumsy way would be `if (Math.abs(Math.abs(str[i+1]) - Math.abs(str[i])) == 1)`. Right now you are using `Math.abs()` to convert digits to numbers. Also, indexing is off, you start from 1, which is good, but then you should compare `[i]` and `[i-1]`. And the usual mismatch: you can say "JUMPING", only at the end. So you should check for `!==1`, and return "NOT JUMPING" inside the loop, and "JUMPING" after. That would handle the 1-digit case too.

It's a more readable practice to use `parseInt()` for making a number from a digit, otherwise the implementation of the comment:

```js
function isJumping(number) {
    let str = number.toString();
    for (let i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(parseInt(str[i-1]) - parseInt(str[i])) !== 1){
            return 'NOT JUMPING';
        }
    }
    return 'JUMPING';
}
console.log(isJumping(345));
console.log(isJumping(3));
console.log(isJumping(79));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check your single digit case, and then see if all the digits vary by just 1

```js
function isJumping(number) {
    let str = number.toString();
    if(str.length == 1)
      return 'JUMPING'
    
    const allByOne = str.substring(1).split('').every( (x,i) => {
      var prev = str[i];
      return  Math.abs( +x - +prev) == 1
    })
   return allByOne ? 'JUMPING' : 'NOT JUMPING';
}
console.log(isJumping(9));
console.log(isJumping(79));
console.log(isJumping(23454));
```

Answer (score 0):

A vaguely functional approach... The `find` gets position of the first character pair where the gap is more than one. The `.filter` deals with negatives (and other extraneous characters) by ignoring them.

```js
// default b to a, so that last digit case, where b===undefined, gives true
const gapIsMoreThanOne = (a,b=a) => ( Math.abs(a-b)>1);
const isDigit = n => /[0-9]/.test(n);

const isJumping = n => n.toString()
  .split("")
  .filter(isDigit)
  .find((x,i,arr)=>gapIsMoreThanOne(x,arr[i+1])) 
  === undefined 
  ? "JUMPING" : "NOT JUMPING"
;

console.log(isJumping(1));         // JUMPING 
console.log(isJumping(12));        // JUMPING
console.log(isJumping(13));        // NOT JUMPING
console.log(isJumping(21));        // JUMPING
console.log(isJumping(21234565));  // JUPING
console.log(isJumping(-21234568)); // NOT JUMPING
console.log(isJumping("313ADVD")); // NOT JUMPING
```

PS: To me "JUMPING" implies that there is a gap greater than one, not that there isn't: but I've gone with how it is in the question.