# why is difference between jquery input element and javascript input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, element

I have two type of call function `check_negative_value()`.
in first type I set the `onchange=change_quantity(this)`and then call `check_negative_value()` from there like:

```
function change_quantity(elem) {
    check_negative_value(elem);
    console.log(elem);
}
```

and in second type I set the `decrement_cart(this)` and then call `check_negative_value()` from there like:

```
function decrement_cart(elem) {
    const input = $(elem).next('input');
    check_negative_value(input);
    console.log(input);
}
```

and in `check_negative_value()` I must use `input.value` or `input.val()` !!

```
function check_negative_value(input){
    if(input.value <= 0){
        alert('not accept value under 1');
        input.value = 1;
    }
}
```

Or :

```
function check_negative_value(input){
    if(input.val() <= 0){
        alert('not accept value under 1');
        input.val(1);
    }
}
```

because each calling function have different element and the result of `console.log` is this:
in jquery call:

```
r.fn.init [input.input-number.text-center, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
```

in javascript call:

```
<input class="input-number text-center" type="number" value="-1" min="0" max="1000" onchange="change_quantity(this)">
```

the html code is :

````
<div class="input-group-button" onclick="decrement_cart(this)">
    <span class="input-number-decrement">-</span>
</div>
<input class="input-number text-center" type="number" min="0" max="1000"
                                    onchange="change_quantity(this)">
<div class="input-group-button" onclick="increment_cart(this)">
    <span class="input-number-increment">+</span>
</div>```
````

how can I use input element in `check_negative_value()` without difference between `input.val()` and `input.value` ???

thanks

Comment: I think you can always use jQuery's val(), if you correctly wrap the element handle in $(), like `$(input).val()`

Comment: Calls to jQuery return jQuery objects. These are different to the Element object in plain JS and have different methods. In your example you need to get the Element object from the jQuery object (`const input = $(elem).next('input').get(0);`) and then pass that to your function. Then the argument will contain a consistent type to use within your function.

Comment: @GrafiCode that will break when the Element object is passed to that function, though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I always get confused when interacting both in vanilla and jquery, but I think it can be handled the same. I tried to reproduce it in this fiddle, it seems to be ok: https://jsfiddle.net/zq1t78c0/

Comment: @GrafiCode if you initalise jquery with a jquery object, it will not "double-wrap" it, but just use the original.  Essentially (pseudo):  `$(obj) => return obj == jquery ? obj : $(obj)`.  So OP can just do `function check_negative_value(input) { input = $(input); .. /*use input as jquery*/ return input.val() }`

Answer (score 2):

**Neither** JavaScript nor jQuery has an `input` element. `input` elements are [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) objects provided by the host environment (browser), not the language (JavaScript) or library (jQuery).

The difference you're seeing is the DOM object (with a `value` property) vs. a jQuery wrapper object around it (with a `val` method).

> how can I use input element in `check_negative_value()` without difference between `input.val()` and `input.value` ???

You can check to see whether what you have is a jQuery wrapper by seeing if it has a `jquery` property or perhaps more directly in this case if it has a `val` property:

```
function check_negative_value(input){
    if (input.jquery) {
        // It's a jQuery wrapper, get the first DOM element it contains from it
        input = input[0];
    }
    if (input.value <= 0){
        alert('not accept value under 1');
        input.value = 1;
    }
}
```

---

Side note: `val()` returns a string (unless the jQuery set is empty), not a number (the value of `value` is also always a string). Although `<= 0` will implicitly convert it, you might consider converting it on purpose as implicit conversion assumes `""` should be `0`; more in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875).

Comment: Note: you're safe to just wrap input inside the function: `function foo(input) { input = $(input); return input.val(); }`.   jquery will recognise when it's a DOM node or a jquery object and not double-wrap if it's already a jquery object. There's always a (very minor) overhead to creating jquery objects as any other object (before someone moans about this as they *always* do).

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for explaining this, I always get confused when wrapping and re-wrapping elements handlers in $(), because it in fact never throws error, and gets always managed by jquery.

Comment: @freedomn-m - Thanks! So long since I wrote jQuery code. :-) I got called away immediately after posting and realised a few minutes later than I normally go the other way, get the DOM element from the jQuery instance, so I update the answer to do that.