# How to parse string | number in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I need add 40 to a `string | number` type, and return a `string | number`. How is it possible in Typescript?

I thought parse it to number, then increase it and return it. But how can I parse a variable which is not sure is string, but it can be number? :)

tried this:

> parseInt(x) - 44

but raised an

```
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `parseInt` use `Number` something like

```
Number(x)
```

Comment: Why would that make any difference to TypeScript? Both `Number` and `parseInt` return numbers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder check this playground link you can see Number works fine with string | number.Also ``parseInt``` parses up to the first non-digit and returns whatever it had parsed so it will treat '123xyz' as number https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=13&pln=2&pc=22#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBDOYBOBLAdgcwD4TQVwFsAjEJAXgHIAWABgoG4AoAYwHs15XQA6YVjABQA5QiSQCoASklA

Comment: I see what you mean (`Number` accepts `any`), you might want to call that out explicitly as well as mentioning how markedly different `Number` and `parseInt` are. (`parseInt` works in your playground as well: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBDOYBOBLAdgcwgHwmgrgLYBGISEAvBAOQAsADNQNwBQAxgPZrwegB0wDhgAUABwCGSeCACSaMMKgBKJUA because of flow analysis) Better example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBDOYBOBLAdgcwgHwmgrgLYBGISEAvBALICGYAFgHRK1oAmA9oQBQCUEADwQADEwCsEAPwQARABYRsiHEUBuAFABjTmnidQTYJww8ADrSTwQASTRgeUPnyA

Answer (score 0):

By checking the type:

```
if (typeof x === "string") {
    x = Number(x); // Or `parseInt` or whatever
}
const result = x - 44;
```

After the `if`, TypeScript will know from flow analysis that `x` has been narrowed from `string | number` to `number`.

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgClQC5EBnKAJxjAHNEAfRMETAI2UoEpSX3PEAbwBQiMYhjBEBKAE9syOFNSIAvOsQAiCtTqauQ0eOMrViAHKsOlIlwDciAPSPEAeUqIABtnSUyyAEkwKE9EOA8AdwALdChkADdOIzEAX2TECAQKREpkMhBcKDVEFQBaRAAWCrt03KgQSiRc-MKatOFMsDI4fAA6XDhaAjQsPEIARgAGSa57Dqye5H7B4YwcfAJNKcn9OaA)

---

For the parsing, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) for your various options. `parseInt` stops at the first non-numeric character and returns whatever number it has at that point (rather than returning `NaN`), which may or may not be your desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To add another option, you could simply make sure that what's passed to `parseInt` is a string using a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
parseInt(`${x}`)
```