# APIGEE - Default values in destructuring declarations are not supported

Tags: javascript, apigee

I am writing a javascript to validate whether client ip is in range of whitelisted IP. I am getting error

> Compilation of JavaScript jsc://ApiKeyPathValidator.js failed with
> error:Compilation error: Default values in destructuring declarations
> are not supported (ApiKeyPathValidator#323). Line:323, column:23.
> Source is:const [range, bits = 32] = cidr.split('/')

Javascript code below

```
const ip4ToInt = ip =>
  ip.split('.').reduce((int, oct) => (int << 8) + parseInt(oct, 10), 0) >>> 0;

const isIp4InCidr = ip => cidr => {
  const [range, bits = 32] = cidr.split('/');
  const mask = ~(2 ** (32 - bits) - 1);
  return (ip4ToInt(ip) & mask) === (ip4ToInt(range) & mask);
};

var whitelistedCidr=['10.0.0.1', '10.1.1.1/21','10.0.0.1'];
var clientIp=getEnv("request.header.X-Forwarded-For");


const isIp4InCidrs = (ip, cidrs) => cidrs.some(isIp4InCidr(ip));
var isInRange=false;
isInRange=isIp4InCidrs(clientIp, whitelistedCidr); 
console.log("Whitelisted IP Test");
console.log(isInRange);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Default values in destructuring declarations are not supported"* is  telling you that the syntax you're using here is not supported:

```
const [range, bits = 32 ] = cidr.split('/');
```

The `const [range, bits = 32]` part is a destructuring declaration, and the `= 32` part is a default value.

That's perfectly valid JavaScript syntax, but apparently it's not supported by the tool you're using. So do it the old fashioned way:

```
const parts = cidr.split('/');
const range = parts[0];
const bits = parts[1] ?? 32;
```

Or similar. (If the tool also doesn't support `??`, you might use `const bits = 1 in parts ? parts[1] : 32;` or `const bits = parts[1] || 32;` depending on how you're going to use `bits`.)

---

Side note: The result of `split` is always an array of **strings**, so with your code (and the amended versions above), in some situations your `bits` constant will contain a string, and other times it'll contain a number (`32`). In general, it's probably best to use one or the other consistently, perhaps by [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) `parts[1]` to number if it's provided.