# Extend class and return object with same methods as parents but different constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, sanitization

I'm trying to extend a class from an external library that contains methods which use its constructor in the input before starting any operation since it can have multiple types. I want to create a Class that works similarly to it but where the input is sanitized.

```
class ParentClass {
    constructor(value: ParentClass.ValueType) {
        // ...
    }

    methodUsingConstructor(otherValue: ParentClass.ValueType) {
        const x = new this.constructor(otherValue)
        // do some stuff here with x ...
        return result;
    }

    // ...
}
```

If I do

```
class SafeParentClass extends ParentClass {
    constructor(value: ParentClass.ValueType) {
        // Do some input sanitizing ...
        super(sanitizedValue);
    }
}
```

I can use `new SafeParentClass(value)`. However, I will get an object with the constructor of the ParentClass. That means that if I do `(new SafeParentClass(value1)).methodUsingConstructor(value2)`, then `value2` is not sanitized and I get an error.

How can I create a `SafeParentClass` such that I can call the methods of the `ParentClass` and they will have a constructor that sanitizes the input?

Example:

```
import { Decimal } from 'decimal.js';

class SafeDecimal extends Decimal {
    constructor(value: Decimal.Value) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            super(parseFloat(value)); // will do super('NaN') if value is not parseable
        } else {
            super(value);
        }
    }
}
```

And then testing it

```
describe('safeDecimal', () => {
    it('should return NaN output with invalid input', () => {
        expect(new SafeDecimal('123123').add('').toString()).toEqual('NaN');
    });
});
```

That throws a `DecimalError`.

Comment: *"I can use `new safeParentClass(value)`. However, I will get an object with the constructor of the `ParentClass`. "* What makes you think that? Are you doing a `return` within your `constructor`? (If so: don't.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm probably mistaken and that's not the case! All I know is that when I call `(new safeParentClass(value1)).methodUsingConstructor(value2)`, and use a value2 that should be sanitized, I get an error because it wasn't.

I'm not using return within the constructor

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Added an example, thank you for the feedback

Comment: What are you expecting `.add('')` to do?

Comment: Return 'NaN', so the whole operation should return 'NaN'.

Comment: FWIW, I added a bit to the end of the answer re `parseFloat`. Happy coding! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way `decimal.js` is written. It overwrites the `constructor` property on **each instance** to be, specifically, `Decimal` (rather than allowing it to be inherited from the prototype, which would be the normal thing). It does that on what is currently line 4,290 in `decimal.mjs` (`x.constructor = Decimal;`). The comment on it says it does that to shadow the inherited one *"...which is `Object`."* (The normal thing would be to fix the inherited one insetad.)

You can fix that by overriding what `decimal.js` does:

```
class SafeDecimal extends Decimal {
    constructor(value: Decimal.Value) {
        if (typeof value === "string") {
            super(parseFloat(value)); // will do super('NaN') if value is not parseable
        } else {
            super(value);
        }
        this.constructor = SafeDecimal; // <=== Here
    }
}
```

Then, your constructor is used and your calculation example works (resulting in `NaN`). I haven't tested other things.

**In the normal case, you wouldn't need this.** It's only necessary because of the specific way `decimal.js` is written.

---

Having said that, you might want to fork it and do the changes you think you need to do in your fork instead.

Finally, you might want to consider doing something more robust than `parseFloat`, since `parseFloat` will happily return `123` for the string `"123asdlfkjasldf"` (whereas it would probably be more reasonable to throw an error or return `NaN`). [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) going into your various options for the tools you might use to build something more robust.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid, you'll have to implement all your methods yourself in the derived class. If the logic of a method of a third-party class doesn't do exactly what you want, you create a derived class and refer to the original method as `super.method(…)`. With this technique, you can first sanitise the input, and then direct it to the original method.

Here's how you do it, basically:

```
class ThirdPartyClass {
  method(argument) {
    // the logic here unsafely uses the argument
  }
}
```

```
class DerivedClass extends ThirdPartyClass {
  override method(argument) {
    const safeArgument = sanitize(argument)

    return super.method(safeArgument)
  }
}
```

You'll have to do that for all methods that you are using.

Comment: Note that `override` is a TypeScript-specific keyword, you can't use it in plain JavaScript code

Comment: Thank you, this is what I started implementing until I realized that there are a lot of methods being used and would prefer a nimbler solution. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! If the third-party library is open-sourced, I'd go to the source code, look for instance methods that are called by as many other methods as possible, and override those methods (instead of overriding every single method, which is tedious).